# Copy table row n times

Tags: tables, foreach

I would like to copy the row of a table, let say, `n` times, but unfortunately my sample below does not compile. It is my understanding that the `\foreach` command should copy what is in its argument but is not doing it here. I have looked at the error message in the compiler and I have an idea as to what may be causing it. I think it is how the table environment is constructed. I am thinking right now of enveloping the command as a group but I don't know how to do this. What is the best way to achieve this result? Some explanation will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {%
    t1 & t2 \\%
    }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\test{3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main problem is that `\foreach` works in a group, but it's not only that.

The simplest thing to do is to first build the table in a macro and then expand it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \def\temp{}%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {%
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp t1 & t2 \\}%
    }%
  \temp}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\test{3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The `\temp` macro is initialized to empty and then augmented at each cycle; at the end it's expanded. The `\gdef` is necessary because of the implicit groups around the cycles.

---

With `\test{3}` what happens is essentially

```
\def\temp{}%
{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp t1 & t2 \\}}%
{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp t1 & t2 \\}}%
{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp t1 & t2 \\}}%
\temp
```

and everything takes place when TeX is still looking for the material in the first cell of the first row. The first line states that `\temp` expands to nothing; then the second line is executed: each `\expandafter` expands the second token after it; for the first two it's another `\expandafter` so we arrive at `\temp`. Hence the second line is equivalent to saying

```
{\gdef\temp{t1 & t2 \\}}
```

but when the same operation is performed in the third line the effect is

```
{\gdef\temp{t1 & t2 \\t1 & t2 \\}}
```

and at the fourth line it becomes

```
{\gdef\temp{t1 & t2 \\t1 & t2 \\t1 & t2 \\}}
```

The supplementary braces represent the implicit group that `\foreach` puts around the cycles. Thus `\gdef` is necessary because otherwise the redefinition of `\temp` would disappear at group end.

The presence of `&` tokens is not a problem, because TeX scans it between braces, so they aren't used for marking the end of a cell. This is an issue that, sometimes, bites someone.

At the end, `\temp` will produce the tokens

```
t1 & t2 \\t1 & t2 \\t1 & t2 \\
```

that will be seen properly by TeX for building the table.

A less readable definition, but which does exactly the same, would be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \let\@temp\@empty
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {%
    \g@addto@macro\@temp{t1 & t2 \\}%
    }%
  \@temp}
\makeatother
```

---

The compulsory LaTeX3 version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\repeatrow}{mm}
 {
  \azet_repeat_row:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_azet_rows_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azet_repeat_row:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_azet_rows_tl
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_azet_rows_tl { #2 \\ } }
  \tl_use:N \l_azet_rows_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\repeatrow{3}{t1 & t2}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The working is very similar to the "classical" solution, but it uses `\prg_replicate:nn` instead of `\foreach`. The command is

```
\prg_replicate:nn { <integer expression> } { <code> }
```

and it evaluates the `<integer expression>` (so one might also call `\repeatrow{3*5}{...}`); then it repeats the `<code>` in the second argument as many times as specified in the first one.

This command is preceded by the analog of `\def\temp{}`: the token list variable `\l_azet_rows_tl` is cleared and the `<code>` is just "append the second argument to `\azet_repeat_row:nn` (which in turn is the "internal" version of `\repeatrow`). Then the contents of the token list variable is delivered for use (the analog of saying `\temp` in the first solution).

Comment: Could you shed more light into the `\expandafter`, `\gdef` and `\temp` commands as I was trying the `\expandafter` by trial and error and didnt get it to work? When can I use them and for what?

Comment: I don't really understand Latex 3 but it is a nice implementation. Could you elaborate? I want to educate myself into the matter.

Answer (score 11):

You don't really need a for-each macro for this, you just need to take care that your loop counter and the groups from the table cells interact correctly.

The following produces the three row table without any large (or small) package overhead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
 t1 & t2 \\
\ifnum#1>1 
  \expandafter\test\expandafter{\numexpr#1-1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}\fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\test{3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While I can _almost_ follow the `\expandafter`s in @egreg's solution, I don't what kind of magic is going here with the last two uses of `\expandafter`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\relax` in your definition above?

Comment: \relax  terminates the e-tex \numexpr expression

Comment: @PeterGrill the last two are stepping over to complete the `\fi` before `\test` is executed so you don't get a build up of pending `\fi` on the input stack

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative using Latex 3,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Copy \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\Copy{4}{t1 & t2 \\}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```