# how to use \loop ... \repeat to generate an arbitrary number of rows in a table

Tags: tables, tex-core, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy table row n times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62177/copy-table-row-n-times)

The code below is intended to produce a table with 3 columns and 3 rows (one
heading and two empty rows) but it can be seen that it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\emptytable[1]{%
  \def\emptyrow{ & & \\ \hline}
  \newcount\rows
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
    %% the following 2 lines create 2 empty rows
    %% \emptyrow
    %% \emptyrow
    %% the following loop doesn't work
    \loop\relax\ifnum\rows<#1 \emptyrow\advance\rows by1\repeat
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\emptytable{2}
\end{document}
```

produces
[image]
instead of
[image]

Why does it not work?

Comment: You can't start a `\loop` in a cell and end it in another, because table cells form groups. There are other examples in the site: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/problem-with-using-loop-inside-the-tabular-environment); [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62177/copy-table-row-n-times)

Answer (score 3):

While egreg's comment applies, you can make your automation idea work via [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) package. Here is a simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcommand{\myemptytable}[1]{
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new1/.style={},
create on use/new2/.style={},
create on use/new3/.style={}
}
{\pgfplotstablenew[columns={new1,new2,new3}]{#1}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={new1,new2,new3},
string type,
columns/new1/.style={column name=A},
columns/new2/.style={column name=B},
columns/new3/.style={column name=C,column type/.add={}{|}},
before row=\hline,
every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
column type/.add={|}{}%
]\loadedtable}
}

\begin{document}

\myemptytable{3}
\myemptytable{6}
\end{document}
```

[image]