# How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?

Tags: tables, tabularx, foreach

I am trying to build a table, and inside the tabularx environment I would like to have a loop, something like (here is a MWE):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}}
    \foreach \r in {1,...,\nRows}{  % https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561791/iteration-in-latex
        \textbf{column1} & two & three & four & five 
    }
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't work, because the ampersands (&) are causing problems. If I escape the &s, then the entire line gets printed in the first column, along with the literal ampersands, kind of like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}}
    \foreach \r in {1,...,\nRows}{  % https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561791/iteration-in-latex
        \textbf{column1} \& two \& three \& four \& five 
    }
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

```
|column1 &      | | | |
| two & three & | | | |
| four & five   | | | |
```

Whereas what I want is:

```
|column 1 | two | three | four | five |
|column 1 | two | three | four | five |
|column 1 | two | three | four | five |
```

....

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I'm actually NOT looking to make identical rows - the rows will be different. This is just a MWE. Thanks!

Edit: I have tried implementing Herbert's answer as recommended in the comments section. It results in no output - just a blank PDF. Here is how I implemented it:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \resettabtoks
    \foreach \r in {1,...,\nRows}{  % https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561791/iteration-in-latex
        % \textbf{column1} \& two \& three \& four \& five 
        \addtabtoks{\textbf{column1} & two & three & four & five \\\hline}%
    }

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}}
\printtabtoks
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Herbert's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo is very much related.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks - I have edited the code, so that now the second section works. @Steven B Segletes: Thanks, I tried that approach but it didn't work - it still gives me errors. I will edit the code to show what I used and there errors I got.

Comment: I have edited the post to show my implementation. It doesn't give any errors, just but gives only a blank output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also you need `\raggedright\arraybackslash` in your preamble.

Comment: You have to use `\global\@tabtoks`, because `\foreach` executes each cycle in a group. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62177/copy-table-row-n-times

Comment: You are also missing `\arraybackslash` after `\raggedright` in the last column specification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presumably you are doing this because you want the rows of the table to depend on the counter in the loop.  In this case you will need a way to add expanded objects to the list of tokens.  Here I add an `\eaddtabtoks` macro in addition to egreg's corrections to the global assignments.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand\eaddtabtoks[1]{\edef\mytmp{#1}\expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\mytmp}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\resettabtoks
\foreach \r in {1,...,\nRows}{
  \addtabtoks{\textbf{column 1} &}
  \eaddtabtoks{row \r}
  \addtabtoks{ & three & four & five \\}%
}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.2cm}*{4}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
\printtabtoks
\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way one could use `\cellcolor{...}` within `\eaddtabtoks{...}`? I'd like to get a conditional coloring of cells. Everything works alright, but when I add `\cellcolor` get various errors, like: `Use of \@@array doesn't match its definition ...`

Comment: @thewaywewalk You might get away with inserting `\noexpand` before `\cellcolor`.   If that doesn't work, ask a new question, showing the code you have.

Comment: It seems to work, thanks for the advice! I finally got away with [another looping structure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313591/36835) yesterday.

Answer (score 14):

You're missing the fact that `\foreach` executes each cycle in a group, so when finishing it the change to `\@tabtoks` is undone.

Add `\global` in the relevant places (and also `\arraybackslash` in the specification for the last column, but this is another problem).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
%%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
%%% variable should always be operated on always locally or always globally
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \r in {1,...,\nRows}{
  \addtabtoks{\textbf{column1} & two & three & four & five \\\hline}%
}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
  @{}
}
\printtabtoks
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

### A more complex example

Suppose we want each table row to depend on the loop index; then some change has to be made. The new `\addtabtoks` macro takes an optional argument that, if expressed, should be the command representing the index in the `\foreach` loop; the mandatory argument, in this case, should be a one parameter macro, like in the code below; the parameter should be the loop index.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
%%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
\newcommand\addtabtoks[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    % no index, just append the second argument
    \global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#2}%
  \else
    % we assume the second argument is a one parameter macro
    \global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\@tabtoks\expandafter#2\expandafter{#1}}%
  \fi
}
%%% variable should always be operated on always locally or always globally
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

% define a one parameter macro for making the row depending on the current index
\newcommand{\tablerow}[1]{%
  \textbf{Row #1} & two & three & four & five \\\hline
}


\begin{document}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \r in {1,...,\nRows}{%
  \addtabtoks{\textbf{column1} & two & three & four & five \\\hline}%
}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
  @{}
}
\hline
\printtabtoks
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\resettabtoks
\foreach \r in {1,...,\nRows}{%
  \addtabtoks[\r]{\tablerow}%
}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright}X
  @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
  @{}
}
\hline
\printtabtoks
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone! All responses were helpful. I have posted a related question here: [link]https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165208/the-thislevelcount-is-available-inside-a-foreachx-loop-but-thislevelitem-is-n would be grateful for additional help. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

If your are open to using (here) another loop than `\foreach` then there are options, like `\xintFor` from package [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint). The syntax is a bit different, and using `\xintFor` at this place does not exclude using `\foreach` at others...

Update adds a second method for people loving the bleeding edge.

> [image: tabularx loop]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}
% \usepackage{tabu} % alternative to tabularx
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
    \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\nRows}}
    \do
    {(\textsl{row #1}) \textbf{column1} & two & three & four & five
    \\ }
\end{tabularx}


% Note with a tabu environment of package tabu, \arraybackslash is not needed
% \begin{tabu} to \textwidth{@{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}}
%     \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\nRows}}
%     \do
%     {(\textsl{row #1}) \textbf{column1} & two & three & four & five
%     \\ }
% \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Here is an idiosyncratic way which relies on an expandable loop (`\xintFor` is not expandable despite the fact it enjoys tabulars), and **without** counters! (`\xintFor` does not use counters either). `\xintiloopindex` can not be within  braces; and in this example we need to hide the tabulations, for the `\xintiloopindex` mechanism to work, because non-expandable material is encountered before.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcommand{\nRows}{5}
\def\TAB{&}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
    \xintiloop [1+1]
    (\bgroup\slshape row \xintiloopindex\egroup )% \xintiloopindex can not be
                                % within braces...
            \textbf{column1} \TAB two \TAB three \TAB four \TAB five \\
    \ifnum\nRows>\xintiloopindex\space
    \repeat
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```