# Build tabular content via \foreach

Tags: tables, loops, foreach

I am trying to build up tabular data using the solution at [How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/how-do-i-use-the-ampersand-inside-a-foreach-or-conditional-or-other-group-e), but not having any success.

There is some expansion issue that I am not able to figure out. I have counters which are declared based on the content of a list and I need to output the value of these counters in the output and hence trying to use `\eAddTableTokens`.  The MWE below yields:

```
 Undefined control sequence.
 \\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                        \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
 l.47 ^^I}
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% This is based on:
%%     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126
%%
\newcommand*{\MyTempTableTokens}{}%
\makeatletter
    \newtoks\@tabtoks
    %%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
    \newcommand\AddTableTokens[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
    \newcommand\eAddTableTokens[1]{% 
        \edef\MyTempTableTokens{#1}%
        \expandafter\AddTableTokens\expandafter{\MyTempTableTokens}%
        }
    %%% variable should always be operated on always locally or always globally
    \newcommand*\ResetTableTokens{\global\@tabtoks{}}
    \newcommand*\PrintTableTokens{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\MyList}{ABC, DE, FG}%

\begin{document}
    % Confirm basic functionality
    \ResetTableTokens%
    \foreach \Entry in \MyList {%
        \AddTableTokens{22 & 44 \\}%
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Basic Testing} \\
        \PrintTableTokens
    \end{tabular}%

    %%% Processing:
    %%%    Counters get declared and appropriate values are computed, 
    %%%    but for MWE these are all just a fixed number.
    \foreach \Entry in \MyList {%
        \newcounter{Count\Entry}%
        \setcounter{Count\Entry}{77}%
    }%
    %%%
    %%% Printing
    \ResetTableTokens%
    \foreach \Entry in \MyList {%
        \edef\TempCountExpanded{\arabic{Count\Entry}}%
        \eAddTableTokens{\Entry & \TempCountExpanded \\}%
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Actual Use Case} \\
        \PrintTableTokens
    \end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't pass ``\\`` through an `\edef`.

Comment: Related Question: [Generate rows in table using \multido (or something similar)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201551/generate-rows-in-table-using-multido-or-something-similar).

Comment: Related Question: [Create Tabular from comma separated parameter list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295718/create-tabular-from-comma-separated-parameter-list).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Commands such as `\\` or `\textbf` don't survive `\edef`; you need `\protected@edef`:

```
\newcommand\eAddTableTokens[1]{%
  \protected@edef\MyTempTableTokens{#1}%
  \expandafter\AddTableTokens\expandafter{\MyTempTableTokens}%
}
```

Comment: Well, this certainly fixed it for the MWE. But, in my actual use case I had to eliminate the `\\ ` in the call to `\eAddTableTokens` and instead add the `\\ ` to definition of `\eAddTableTokens`.  But, I am unable to determine what the actual difference between my actual use case and MWE is that could be causing this.