# logarithm, sine, cosine etc evaluated in tabular

Tags: fp, spreadtab

I know that I can use [`spreadtab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) to make automatic calculations in a tabular. However, I only managed to do simple operations like `+-*/`, but I have no idea how to make more complex ones like `log`, `ln`, `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `exp`.

I tried to insert some [`fp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp) functions in the `spreadtab`, but only receive errors.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{cc}}
    @number & @$\ln$(number)\\
    10 & \FPln{\result}{a2} \result
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

It gives the error: `Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \end{spreadtab}`.

Comment: Please see [why should the `minimal` class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided).

Comment: You are right, `standalone` class was the wanted result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you can use the `ln` and `sin` functions directly:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{fp}

\usepackage{numprint}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\numprint{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ccc}}\toprule
    @$x$ & @$\ln(x)$ & @$\sin(x)$ [$x$ in degrees] \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
     15  & ln(a2)    & sin(a2*pi/180) \\
     30  & ln(a3)    & sin(a3*pi/180) \\
     45  & ln(a4)    & sin(a4*pi/180) \\
     90  & ln(a5)    & sin(a5*pi/180) \\
     \bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, and sin(), cos() also.
My bad I did not check that correctly, I tried with log() and didn't found informations about theses functions in the `spreadtab` manual.
Should I delete my question, or would it be better to keep it so other distracted people may find the answer?

Comment: @Togh: My usual opinion is to _not_ delete a question -- What you did is exactly what I would have tried, so am sure that others will run into the similar problems in the future.

Comment: Oops. Well you might be interested in a more powerful way of dealing with mathematical calculations which I've already posted below.

Comment: `ln()`, `exp()`, `^`, `sin()`, `cos()` and `tan()` works too.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using the powerful [`xfp`](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfp.pdf) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Precision{4} % calculation precision

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = \Precision,
  group-digits = false
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\DeclareSIUnit[mode = text]\radian{rad}

\begin{document}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201554/15874
\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\skyIDtable{}
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{10}{\protected@xdef\skyIDtable{\skyIDtable
      \i
    & \fpeval{round(ln(\i),\Precision)}   % logarithmic
    & \fpeval{round(sin(\i),\Precision)}  % sine (radian)
    & \fpeval{round(sind(\i),\Precision)} % sine (degrees)
    & \fpeval{round(tan(\i),\Precision)}  % tangent (radian)
    & \fpeval{round(tand(\i),\Precision)} % tangent (degrees)
    & \fpeval{round(exp(\i),\Precision)}  % exponential
    \\}}
\makeatother

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format =  2]
    S[table-format =  1.\Precision]
    S[table-format = -1.\Precision]
    S[table-format =  1.\Precision]
    S[table-format = -1.\Precision]
    S[table-format =  1.\Precision]
    S[table-format =  5.\Precision]
  }
   \toprule
     {$x$} & {$\ln x$} & {$\sin x$}     & {$\sin x$}     & {$\tan x$}     & {$\tan x$}     & {$\exp x$} \\
     {---} & {---}     & {\si{\radian}} & {\si{\degree}} & {\si{\radian}} & {\si{\degree}} & {---}      \\
   \midrule
     \skyIDtable
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update**

Note that log_[b], i.e. the logarithm in base b, is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX was designed for typesetting. If you're going to use it for mathematical calculation too then you should consider the [`sagetex` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/). It's using the power of a computer algebra system [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/) allows you to calculations and plot and place them anywhere you want. In the case of tables you can have Sage typeset them for you (as in the example below) which saves a lot of time and eliminates mistakes. The `sagetex` package requires you to have access to Sage. You can get that through a free [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com) account or you can install Sage locally on your computer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{sagesilent}
var('x')
f(x) = sin(x*pi/180.)
g(x) = cos(x*pi/180.)
h(x) = tan(x*pi/180.)
m(x) = tan(x)

output = ""
output += r"\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc} "
output += r" degrees & sine & cosine & tangent & & degrees & sine & cosine &   tangent \\ \hline "
for i in range(1, 5):
    output += r"%d & %8.4f & %8.4f & %8.4f & & %d & %8.4f & % 8.4f & %12.4f  \\ "%(i, f(i), g(i), h(i), i+45, f(i+45), g(i+45), h(i+45))
output += r"\end{tabular}"
\end{sagesilent}
\begin{center}
\sagestr{output}
\end{center}
You can do the traditional table entering data cell by cell:\\
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
$\sage{f(45).n(digits=5)}$ & $\sage{cos(pi/3).n(digits=4)}$ &   $\sage{log(8,2).n(digits=4)}$\\
 \hline
 $\sage{ln(7).n(digits=4)}$ & $\sage{m(pi/3).n(digits=4)}$ &      $\sage{exp(2).n(digits=5)}$\\ 
\end{tabular}

Or you can do calculations inline:
What's the value of $e^{5}$? It's $\sage{(e^5)}$. That's not helpful.
What is it as a decimal? It's $\sage{(e^5).n(digits=8)}$.

What's $\log_2(8)$? It's $\sage{log(8,2)}$. 
\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of the code running in Sagemath Cloud:
[image]

Note that the for loop beginning with
for i in range(1, 5):
produces 4 lines of the table because i must be less than the last number. You can change 5 to a bigger number and have Sage create the table for you.

Comment: Using `python` could be a more familiar programming way to me, good to have pointed this possibility to use `sage`.
Does it require `-shell-escape` ?

Comment: Sagetex gives you both Python and Sage commands. It requires `-shell-escape` but if you're using Sagemath Cloud then everything is taken care of automatically.