# Automatically generating table using \multido

Tags: tables, automation, multido

First: This question is similar to [Generate rows in table using \multido (or something similar)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201551/generate-rows-in-table-using-multido-or-something-similar).

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand*\nederst[1]{\calc{#1*(#1+1)/2}}
\newcommand*\iAlt[1]{\calc{#1*(#1+1)*(#1+2)/6}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\skyIDtable{}
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{6}{%
    \protected@xdef\skyIDtable{\skyIDtable \i & \i & \i & \nederst{\i} & \iAlt{\i}\\}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{table}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{
    *{3}{S[table-format = 1]}
    *{2}{S[table-format = 2]}
  }
   \toprule
    {Long text~A} & {Long text~B} & {Long text~C} & {Long text~D} & {Long text~E} \\
   \midrule
    \skyIDtable
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I would like to switch the columns with the rows to get the following:

[image: wanted]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More complicated code, but way simpler syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse,siunitx,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\nederst}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { #1 * (#1+1)/2 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\iAlt}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { #1 * ( #1 + 1 ) * ( #1 + 2 ) / 6 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{smmmm}
 {% * = transpose
  % #2 = number of iterations
  % #3 = column/row headers
  % #4 = table preamble
  % #5 = entry specs
  \svend_preparetable:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #5 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \__svend_make_table_rows:nn { #3 } { #4 } }
   { \__svend_make_table_columns:nn { #3 } { #4 } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_svend_tablebody_tl
\prop_new:N \l_svend_entries_prop
\int_new:N \l_svend_rows_int
\int_new:N \l_svend_columns_int

\cs_new:Npn \svend_prop_item:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \prop_item:Nn #1 { #2, #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \svend_prop_item:Nnn { Nnf , Nfn }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_preparetable:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {% #1=iterations; #2=column/row headers; #3=specs
  \int_set:Nn \l_svend_columns_int { \clist_count:n { #2 } }
  \int_set:Nn \l_svend_rows_int { #1 }
  \prop_clear:N \l_svend_entries_prop
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_rows_int }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
     {
      \prop_put:Nnf \l_svend_entries_prop { ##1,####1 }
       {
        \clist_item:nn { #3 } { ####1 }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nnf }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__svend_make_table_columns:nn #1 #2
 {
  % start making the table body
  \tl_set:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl
   {
    \begin{tabular}{ #2 }\toprule
   }

  % the header row
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
     {
      \int_compare:nF { ##1 == 1 } { & }
      { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \\ \midrule } % finish the row

  % the table body proper
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_rows_int }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
       {
        \int_compare:nF { ####1 == 1 } { & }
        \svend_prop_item:Nnn \l_svend_entries_prop { ##1 } { ####1 }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \\ }
   }

  % finish up the table body
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \bottomrule \end{tabular} }

  % produce the table
  \tl_use:N \l_svend_tablebody_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__svend_make_table_rows:nn #1 #2
 {
  % start building the table body
  \tl_set:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl
   {
    \begin{tabular}{ #2 }\toprule
   }

  % the table body proper
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
     {
      \clist_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } &
     }
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_rows_int }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
       {
        \int_compare:nF { ####1 == 1 } { & }
        \svend_prop_item:Nnn \l_svend_entries_prop { ####1 } { ##1 }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \\ }
   }
  % finish up the table body
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \bottomrule \end{tabular} }

  % produce the table
  \tl_use:N \l_svend_tablebody_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printtable
 {6}
 { Long text A, Long text B, Long text C, Long text D, Long text E }
 { *{3}{S[table-format = 1]} *{2}{S[table-format = 2]} }
 { #1,#1,#1,\nederst{#1},\iAlt{#1} }

\bigskip

\printtable*
 {6}
 { Opstillingsnummer, Antal lag, Antal bægre i bundes side,
   Antal bægre i nederste lag, Antal bægre i optillingen }
 { l *{6}{S[table-format = 2]} }
 { #1,#1,#1,\nederst{#1},\iAlt{#1} }

\bigskip

\printtable
 {7}
 { Long text A, Long text B, Long text C, Long text D, Long text E }
 { *{3}{S[table-format = 1]} *{2}{S[table-format = 2]} }
 { #1,#1,#1,\nederst{#1},\iAlt{#1} }

\bigskip

\printtable*
 {7}
 { Opstillingsnummer, Antal lag, Antal bægre i bundes side,
   Antal bægre i nederste lag, Antal bægre i optillingen }
 { l *{7}{S[table-format = 2]} }
 { #1,#1,#1,\nederst{#1},\iAlt{#1} }

\end{document}
```

[image]

The table entries are computed and stored in a property list, indexed by `row,column`.

Then the table is printed columnwise (no *) or rowwise, gathering the appropriate index from the property list.

The first argument is the number of iteration, the second argument is the comma separated list of column or row headers (used for determining the number of columns/rows), the third argument is the table preamble; finally come the specifiers, where `#1` is used for the current integer.

Comment: I've added another question for you at the bottom of my original question.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Please, remove the addition, as it doesn't belong to the question. Why not using spaces, as they are ignored in the programming environment? Control sequence names can't have spaces in them, of course.

Comment: Okay. Removed. (I was just wondering, that's all.)

Comment: Hi again egreg. How do I get a comma (`,`) instead of a full stop (`.`) as decimal separator in the entries? (I can of course wrap the entries in the fifth argument to `\printtable` in a `\num` from [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) but I would like to not have to do this every time (do to laziness).)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Since the table uses `siunitx` features, you should try issuing `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}` in the document preamble.

Comment: Hmmm ... That doesn't seem to work. (I'll create a MWE and add it to me question.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg No, please; open a new one.

Answer (score 5):

I show the plain TeX-like solution but it works in LaTeX too because only eTeX primitives and `\newcount` macro are used. We needn't any LaTeX packages.

```
\def\nederst#1{\the\numexpr #1*(#1+1)/2 \relax}
\def\iAlt#1{\the\numexpr #1*(#1+1)*(#1+2)/6 \relax}

\newcount\i \i=1
\def\skyIDtable{
   \the\i & \the\i & \the\i & \hbox to1em{\hss\nederst\i} & \hbox to1em{\hss\iAlt\i}
   \global\advance\i by 1
   \ifnum\i<7 \global\let\next=\skyIDtable \else \global\let\next=\empty \global\i=1 \fi
   \cr \next
}
\def\trline#1{#11 & #12 & #13 & #14 & #15 & #16 \cr}
\def\skyIDtableT{
   Opstillingsnummer            & \trline\relax  
   Antal lag                    & \trline\relax  
   Antal bægre i bundes side    & \trline\relax  
   Antal bægre i nederste lag   & \trline\nederst
   Antal bægre i optillingen    & \trline\iAlt
}

\def\toprule{\noalign{\smallskip\hrule height1pt\smallskip}}\let\botrule=\toprule
\def\midrule{\noalign{\smallskip\hrule\smallskip}}

Normal table:

\hfil\vbox{\halign{&\enspace\hfil#\unskip\hfil\enspace \cr
   \toprule
   Long text A & Long text B & Long text C & Long text D & Long text E \cr
   \midrule   
   \skyIDtable
   \botrule
}}

Transposed table:

\hfil\vbox{\halign{\enspace #\unskip\enspace\hfil&&\enspace\hfil#\unskip\enspace\cr
   \toprule
   \skyIDtableT
   \botrule
}}

\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

The transposition is not as straight-forward. You'll have to cycle through each row individually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,multido,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand*\nederst[1]{\calc{#1*(#1+1)/2}}
\newcommand*\iAlt[1]{\calc{#1*(#1+1)*(#1+2)/6}}

\begin{document}

\centering

\makeatletter
\newcommand\skyIDtable{}
\multido{\i=1+1}{6}{% Construct 6 rows
  \protected@xdef\skyIDtable{\skyIDtable \i & \i & \i & \nederst{\i} & \iAlt{\i}\protect\\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{
  *{3}{S[table-format = 1]}
  *{2}{S[table-format = 2]}
}
 \toprule
 {Long text~A} & {Long text~B} & {Long text~C} & {Long text~D} & {Long text~E} \\
 \midrule
 \skyIDtable
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% Transposed table

\makeatletter
\newcommand\skyIDtableT{Long text A}% First column ID
\multido{\i = 1+1}{6}{\protected@xdef\skyIDtableT{\skyIDtableT & \i}}% Add first row entries
\g@addto@macro{\skyIDtableT}{\protect\\ Long text B}% Add another first column ID
\multido{\i = 1+1}{6}{\protected@xdef\skyIDtableT{\skyIDtableT & \i}}% Add second row entries
\g@addto@macro{\skyIDtableT}{\protect\\ Long text C}% Add another first column ID
\multido{\i = 1+1}{6}{\protected@xdef\skyIDtableT{\skyIDtableT & \i}}% Add third row entries
\g@addto@macro{\skyIDtableT}{\protect\\ Long text D}% Add another first column ID
\multido{\i = 1+1}{6}{\protected@xdef\skyIDtableT{\skyIDtableT & \nederst{\i}}}% Add fourth row entries
\g@addto@macro{\skyIDtableT}{\protect\\ Long text E}% Add another first column ID
\multido{\i = 1+1}{6}{\protected@xdef\skyIDtableT{\skyIDtableT & \iAlt{\i}}}% Add fifth row entries
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{6}{S[table-format = 2]}
}
 \toprule
 \skyIDtableT \\% Insert constructed table
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```