# Comma, not full stop, as decimal separator in numbers in siunitx table

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following code (taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219100/15874) by egreg):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,siunitx,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\dage}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { 540 * ( #1 - 1 ) }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\diastase}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { 20 / 2^( #1 - 1 ) }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{smmmm}
 {% * = transpose
  % #2 = number of iterations
  % #3 = column/row headers
  % #4 = table preamble
  % #5 = entry specs
  \svend_preparetable:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #5 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \__svend_make_table_rows:nn { #3 } { #4 } }
   { \__svend_make_table_columns:nn { #3 } { #4 } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_svend_tablebody_tl
\prop_new:N \l_svend_entries_prop
\int_new:N \l_svend_rows_int
\int_new:N \l_svend_columns_int

\cs_new:Npn \svend_prop_item:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \prop_item:Nn #1 { #2, #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \svend_prop_item:Nnn { Nnf , Nfn }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_preparetable:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {% #1=iterations; #2=column/row headers; #3=specs
  \int_set:Nn \l_svend_columns_int { \clist_count:n { #2 } }
  \int_set:Nn \l_svend_rows_int { #1 }
  \prop_clear:N \l_svend_entries_prop
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_rows_int }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
     {
      \prop_put:Nnf \l_svend_entries_prop { ##1,####1 }
       {
        \clist_item:nn { #3 } { ####1 }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nnf }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__svend_make_table_columns:nn #1 #2
 {
  % start making the table body
  \tl_set:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl
   {
    \begin{tabular}{ #2 }\toprule
   }

  % the header row
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
     {
      \int_compare:nF { ##1 == 1 } { & }
      { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \\ \midrule } % finish the row

  % the table body proper
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_rows_int }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
       {
        \int_compare:nF { ####1 == 1 } { & }
        \svend_prop_item:Nnn \l_svend_entries_prop { ##1 } { ####1 }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \\ }
   }

  % finish up the table body
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \bottomrule \end{tabular} }

  % produce the table
  \tl_use:N \l_svend_tablebody_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__svend_make_table_rows:nn #1 #2
 {
  % start building the table body
  \tl_set:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl
   {
    \begin{tabular}{ #2 }\toprule
   }

  % the table body proper
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_columns_int }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
     {
      \clist_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } &
     }
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_svend_rows_int }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_svend_tablebody_tl
       {
        \int_compare:nF { ####1 == 1 } { & }
        \svend_prop_item:Nnn \l_svend_entries_prop { ####1 } { ##1 }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \\ }
   }
  % finish up the table body
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_svend_tablebody_tl { \bottomrule \end{tabular} }

  % produce the table
  \tl_use:N \l_svend_tablebody_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {,}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \printtable*
   {5}
   {Antal d{\o}gn \hspace*{0.5em},
    Diastasetal}
   {l *{5}{c}}
   {\dage{#1}, \diastase{#1}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why are the decimals numbers printed with a full spot and not a comma as decimal separator? (I followed egreg's suggestion in a comment and added

```
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {,}
}
```

to the preamble but that does help for some reason.)

Comment: kinda hard to find, but relevant: [Switching decimal mark between comma and dot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133915/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `siunitx` features for the table columns:

```
\begin{table}
  \printtable*
   {5}
   {Antal d{\o}gn \hspace*{0.5em},
    Diastasetal}
   {l *{5}{S[table-parse-only]}}
   {\dage{#1}, \diastase{#1}}
\end{table}
```

will print

[image]

Consult the manual of `siunitx` for other options to the `S` column type.

Comment: Arrrh! I see. Can it be implemented into the code so that I don't have to write `S[table-parse-only]` every time?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg You may want different options for different tables. But you can define a new column type with `\newcolumntype{N}{S[table-parse-only}` and use `*{5}{N}`.