# Include \hrule within tabular rows generated using \foreach

Tags: tables, foreach, hline

This question extends the solution from [Generate rows in table using \multido (or something similar)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201551/generate-rows-in-table-using-multido-or-something-similar).  Based on the solution to the linked question, I understand how to use a `\foreach` loop to build rows for a tabular table.  My question is how can I include a horizontal line (border) between each row?  In a static tabular I would include `\hline` but that doesn't seem to work when using the `\foreach` loop.

Edit 1 ---

MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Buildtable}{%
    \def\tableData{}% empty table
    \foreach \n in {1,...,5}{%
        \protected@xdef\tableData{\tableData \n  & A\n & B\n & C\n \\} % < adding \hline here causes error
    }
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
            \textbf{Num} & \textbf{Col A} & \textbf{Col B} & \textbf{Col C} \\ \hline
        \tableData \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \Buildtable
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

I'm looking to achieve the equivalent of "all borders" in Excel (shown below).

[image]

Adding `\hline` within the braces, but after `\\`, on the indicated line results in the error

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.19     \Buildtable
```

I do not understand why adding this causes an error.

Comment: please always show a small but complete example. if by `\foreach` you mean the loop from pgf that adds a tex group around each iteration so is usually unsuitable for generating table rows. you may have worked around that but then whether or not `\hline` works depends on code you have not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\hline` won't survive multiple `\protected@xdef` instructions. You can `\let` it to `\relax` in the loop cycles, it will have its standard meaning when doing `\Buildtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Buildtable}{%
  \def\tableData{}% empty table
  \foreach \n in {1,...,5}{%
    \let\hline\relax
    \protected@xdef\tableData{\tableData \n  & A\n & B\n & C\n \\ \hline}
  }
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Num} & \textbf{Col A} & \textbf{Col B} & \textbf{Col C} \\ \hline
    \tableData
  \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \Buildtable
\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

Here's a generic command for generating such tables by giving the number of columns and rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Buildtable}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of columns, #2 = number of rows
  \doomedjupiter_buildtable:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \doomedjupiter_buildtable:nn
 {
  % header
  \tl_set:Nn \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl { \hline \textbf{Num} }
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl
     {
       & \textbf{Col ~ \int_to_Alph:n { ##1 }}
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl { \\ \hline }
  % make rows
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl { ##1 }
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl { & \int_to_Alph:n { ####1 } ##1 }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl { \\ \hline }
   }
  % make the table
  \begin{tabular}{|l|*{#1}{l|}}
  \tl_use:N \l__doomedjupiter_buildtable_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Buildtable{3}{5}

\bigskip

\Buildtable{6}{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]