Issues with Misplaced Alignment Tab Character and Table Width in tabularray Environment
I've adapted the code below from this answer to switch from the tabular environment to the tblr environment from the tabularray package. While the original code works perfectly with tabular, I'm encountering problems with tblr. Specifically, I get these errors:

Misplaced alignment tab character &.
Package tabularray: Table width is too small, need .....pt more!

Here is the code:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_authors_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}
{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_authors_clist { #1 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \formatNames:n #1
{
  \clist_map_inline:Nn { #1 }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eF {##1}
    {
      &
      \seq_clear_new:N \l__tempa_seq
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tempa_seq {, } { ##1 }
      \tl_if_blank:eTF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 1 }}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:eF {
          \seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }
        }
        {
          {\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n \MakeUppercase{\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}}
        }
      }
      {
        {
          \tl_trim_spaces:n {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 1 }}
        }
        \tl_if_blank:eF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}
        {
          {\c_space_token\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n \MakeUppercase{\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}}
        }
      }
    \\
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAuthors}{}
{
  \begin{tblr}{|l|l|}
    Author
    \int_compare:nNnT {\clist_count:N \g_authors_clist} > 1 { s }
    \formatNames:n { \g_authors_clist }
  \end{tblr}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\authors{%
  {firstName, lastName},%
  {firstName, lastName},%
  {firstName, lastName},%
  {firstName, lastName}
}

\begin{document}

\printAuthors{}

\end{document}

I suspect the issues are related to the handling of the & alignment character and the overall width of the table. However, I'm unsure how to resolve these errors.

\cs_new_protected:Npn \formatNames:n #1 {   \clist_map_inline:Nn #1 looks wrong the outer command is defined to accept an n argument such as  {my name} but it passes the argument to \clist_map_inline:Nn as an N argument which must be a single unbraced token,

Thanks for the reply, I had not noticed it until you mentioned it. But why didn't the compiler complain about it? Does expl3 allow this kind of error? @DavidCarlisle

oh sure it doesn't track the argument type at definition time, it would of course give a run time error if you actually did pass in multiple tokens. more is tracked at defintion time if you turn on debug checking

So you mean I need to use \formatNames:n { \g_authors_clist } instead of \formatNames:n \g_authors_clist? @DavidCarlisle

no use :N form for both since you need the :N form to map over a clist variable.  But your real issue is that you can't use & in the inline map over a list within the tabular as that ends the current group so breaks the iteration, what you can do is iterate over a list to built a table row in a macro and then use that macro.

Thanks for the explanation! I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge in expl3 to implement that. Could you provide an example of how to do this, or point me to a similar answer or resource where I can learn more? @DavidCarlisle

here for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201551/generate-rows-in-table-using-multido-or-something-similar

Thanks! I'll give it a try and see how to apply it to my use case. @DavidCarlisle

Could you please lend a hand? I've tried all the methods I found but I keep encountering strange errors. Every time I think I've found a solution, something else goes wrong, and I'm stuck in this frustrating loop. I'm facing an XY problem. I originally wanted to create a table that matches the page width and takes values from a comma-separated list of lists. Someone kindly suggested a solution that almost works, but I still need to use the tblr environment instead of tabular. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. @DavidCarlisle

I think skillmon has answered this at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719473/how-to-properly-expand-expl3-macros-within-tblr-environment-from-tabularray-pac and we can close this as duplicate?

What is the desired output?  A table, two columns, top-left cell "Author" or "Authors", right column: Names of authors?

Yeah, he did. Thank you too, David, for all your help and explanations

I guess usage of \tl_trim_spaces:n in your example is wrong.

Seems, with the mapping of the last element you get an unneeded \\\.

@UlrichDiez Here is the original question from where I started. I asked about creating macros to generate a thesis title page from comma-separated lists.
