How to properly expand expl3 Macros within tblr environment (from tabularray package)
I've been working on a macro that takes a comma-separated list of lists and converts it into a table that spans the full width of the page, with specific text formatting applied to certain columns. Thanks to a user here on stackexchange who has provided a helpful solution, I've been able to make significant progress, but I'm still struggling with one remaining issue: The generated table does not stretch to fill the page width.
I've tried various solutions to make the tabular environment take the full width of the page, including using resizebox and external packages like tabularray for more flexible table layouts. However, all my attempts resulted in errors, and trying to fix these errors only led to more problems.
I would like to switch from the tabular environment to the tblr environment from the tabularray package. According to the tabularray documentation (Section 3.2: Outer Specifications > 3: Expand Macros First), the tblr environment behaves differently from traditional tabular environment:

In contrast to traditional tabular environment, tabularray environments need to see every & and \\ when splitting the table body with l3regex. And you can not put cell text inside any table command defined with \NewTableCommand. But you could use outer key expand to make tabularray expand every occurrence of any of the specified macros once and in the given oder before splitting the table body. Note that you can not expand a command defined with \NewDocumentCommand. You can also use expand+ if you still want to keep the macros in the current expand setting.


To expand a command without optional argument, you can define it with \newcommand. To expand commands with optional arguments, you can not define them with \newcommand. But you can define them with \NewExpandableDocumentCommand, and use option expand=\expanded to do exhaustive expansions.


Note that you need to protect fragile commands (if any) inside them with \unexpanded command.

Could someone guide me on how to adapt the code below to use the tblr environment from the tabularray package?
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_thesis_committee_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\thesisCommittee}{m}
{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_thesis_committee_clist { #1 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \formatNames:n #1
{
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eF {##1}{
      &
      \seq_clear_new:N \l__tempa_seq
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tempa_seq { , } { ##1 }
      \tl_if_blank:eTF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 1 }}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:eF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}{{\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}}}
      }
      {
        {\tl_trim_spaces:n {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 1 }}} \tl_if_blank:eF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}{{\c_space_token\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}}}
      }
    \\
    }
  }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \formatCommittee:n #1
{
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eF {##1}{
      \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
      \clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist
      \clist_gset:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_log:N \l_tmpa_clist
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { \tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 }} ~ {\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 2 }}} }
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { Professor ~ at ~ \tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 3 }} }
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { \tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 4 }} }
      \clist_log:N \l_tmpb_clist
      \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { & } \\
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printThesisCommittee}{}
{
  \begin{tblr}{lll}
    \formatCommittee:n \g_thesis_committee_clist
  \end{tblr}
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\thesisCommittee{
  {firstNAME1, lastName1, institute1, role1},
  {firstNAME2, lastName2, institute2, role2},
  {firstNAME3, lastName3, institute3, role3}
}

\begin{document}

  \printThesisCommittee{}
  
\end{document}


Please note that your \formatComittee:n should be \formatComittee:N as it expects a single token (the clist-variable) as its argument. Same is true for \formatNames:n which should be \formatNames:N. Also neither your variable nor your functions have a suitable module in their name. They should be called \<module>_format_names:N or \g_<module>_thesis_committee_clist.

I'm afraid since neither of your macros are expandable you can't really expand them before tblr reads its contents. You could restructure your usage of tblr to first build a tl of the contents you want to output in the tblr environment and then expand that variable before tblr starts reading its contents.

why do you want to use a tabular, and even more a complicated tabular like tblr, for such a simple layout? you could do that with simple boxes ...

thank you for the quick reply, another user mentioned this to me earlier (changing :n to :N), but I couldn't grasp it until I realized that these definitions have specific rules to follow. I'm currently learning about them. @Skillmon

Also you're using global assignments on the local variable \l_tmpa_clist, either use \g_tmpa_clist instead or use \clist_set:Nn instead of \clist_gset:Nn. Additionally the scratch variables are not meant to be used in a package, so if you're creating a package or class or the like, please use module specific variables.

Honestly, I don't have a particular reason for choosing one method over another. I use the tabular environment for tasks like this simply because it's something I've seen many others do, so I followed suit. :-) @UlrikeFischer

Another issue: Your usage of \tl_trim_spaces:n doesn't work, all it sees is \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} without any spaces, you'll want to use \tl_trim_spaces:e at that spot to first expand the \clist_item:Nn.

@Mycroft_47 in that case, you might want to use a standard tabular instead of tblr. Not that it's absolutely easy to handle, but for simple stuff it's preferable, imho. Faster, more predictable, you don't have to work around tblr's argument grabbing.

Thanks, If I use the classic tabular environment, how can I ensure that it fills the width of the page? I want all the columns to be evenly spaced. @Skillmon

@Mycroft_47 you don't get that from your tblr usage either, it will just left-align the individual columns.

I mean, if I create a tblr table with X columns, I can ensure that there's an even spacing between each of these columns. @Skillmon

@Mycroft_47 yes, but you get the same with tabularx which is still faster and easier to use, imho. But note that this might not lead to the most pleasing look. For instance for your test document (and making the printing actually work) you get a basically empty role-column, but the surname of your committee members get hyphenated because they don't fit.

Yeah, I've been using tabularx for these tasks until recently. I decided to stick with one package that's still maintained instead of loading several packages, each dealing with a specific aspect of tables. This keeps my project's preamble clean with only necessary imports. Also, compilation time hasn't been a big concern for most of my work. As you mentioned, the main focus is on achieving a visually pleasing result. @Skillmon

there are reasons to switch if you need to but "maintenance" is not one of them, tabularx is part of the core latex release, if you don't trust that it is being maintained, you should not trust latex at all.

Yes, of course. I mentioned maintenance as a reason because I couldn't find the right word in my limited English vocabulary to express the idea I had in mind. @DavidCarlisle

The following works for tabular, tabularx, and tblr, just use whichever of the environments you want. But note that blindly giving all columns the same width gives ugly results. Please note that this is not how I'd do any of that, this is just an answer to your problem showing how you could access your expl3 variables to build a tabular-like environment.
I dropped the \tl_trim_spaces:n because l3clist will trim spaces when parsing a clist on its own, no need to redo that. I also dropped the usage of the second clist and instead build an output tl.
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_mycroft_thesis_committee_clist
\clist_new:N \l_mycroft_tmpa_clist
\tl_new:N \l_mycroft_tmpa_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\thesisCommittee}{m}
  {
    \clist_gset:Nn \g_mycroft_thesis_committee_clist { #1 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mycroft_format_committee:NN #1#2
{
  \tl_clear:N #2
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
    {
      \tl_if_blank:nF {##1}
        {
          \clist_set:Nn \l_mycroft_tmpa_clist {##1}
          \clist_log:N \l_mycroft_tmpa_clist
          \tl_put_right:Ne #2
            {
              \clist_item:Nn \l_mycroft_tmpa_clist { 1 } ~
              \group_begin:
                \exp_not:N \bfseries
                \clist_item:Nn \l_mycroft_tmpa_clist { 2 }
              \group_end:
              & Professor ~ at ~ \clist_item:Nn \l_mycroft_tmpa_clist { 3 }
              & \clist_item:Nn \l_mycroft_tmpa_clist { 4 }
              \exp_not:N \\
            }
        }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printThesisCommittee}{}
{
  \mycroft_format_committee:NN
    \g_mycroft_thesis_committee_clist
    \l_mycroft_tmpa_tl
  \use:e
    {
      \exp_not:N \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*3X}
        \exp_not:V \l_mycroft_tmpa_tl
      \exp_not:N \end{tabularx}
    }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\thesisCommittee{
  {firstNAME1, lastName1, institute1, role1},
  {firstNAME2, lastName2, institute2, role2},
  {firstNAME3, lastName3, institute3, role3}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\printThesisCommittee
\end{document}



Alternative approach: Work by being fully expandable, then in tlbr use the expand=\expanded approach and wrap your command in \expanded. In tabular or tabularx you don't have to do anything special, just directly use your macro:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_mycroft_thesis_committee_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\thesisCommittee}{m}
  {
    \clist_gset:Nn \g_mycroft_thesis_committee_clist { #1 }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \mycroft_format_committee:N #1
  { \exp_not:e { \clist_map_function:NN #1 \__mycroft_format_committee:n } }
\cs_new:Npn \__mycroft_format_committee:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nF {#1}
      {
        \clist_item:nn {#1} { 1 }~
        \group_begin: \exp_not:N \bfseries \clist_item:nn {#1} { 2 } \group_end:
        & Professor~ at~ \clist_item:nn {#1} { 3 }
        & \clist_item:nn {#1} { 4 }
        \exp_not:N \\
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printThesisCommittee}{}
  {
    \noindent
    \begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{*3X}
      \expanded{\mycroft_format_committee:N \g_mycroft_thesis_committee_clist}
    \end{tblr}
    \par
    \medskip
    Or\par
    \medskip
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*3X}
      \mycroft_format_committee:N \g_mycroft_thesis_committee_clist
    \end{tabularx}
  }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\thesisCommittee{
  {firstNAME1, lastName1, institute1, role1},
  {firstNAME2, lastName2, institute2, role2},
  {firstNAME3, lastName3, institute3, role3}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\printThesisCommittee
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer and all the explanations. Everything is working perfectly now. Thanks again @Skillmon
