# Create Tabular from comma separated parameter list

Tags: tables, multicolumn, loops

I tried to find an answer to this but currently I have no idea how to get it to work.

I want to create a new command which fills some lines of a tabular based on a given list with variable length like

```
\makeTabularRows{item1, item2, item3}
```

The output of this should be

```
\multicolumn{3}{c}{item1} & \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{item2} & \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{item3} &
```

So that it fits in a tabular like

```
\begin{tabular}{lclr}
    \makeTabularRows{item1, item2, item3}
\end{tabular}
```

I found a lot of partial solutions for example this short one

```
\newcommand{\makeTabularRows}[1]{%
    \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{.}}%  
    \@for \el:=#1\do{\nextitem\el}%
}
```

to insert dots between the elements and other solutions looking more complex for example to create an enumeration. I found out that one problem is to include the & sign and my tests showed me that even inserting the \\ seems to be not possible. I am lost to find a solution for the tabular if there is one.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Can you give some more context? Why the `\multicolumn`?

Comment: as soon as TeX will "see" a `&` all definitions will be lost (for the next cell). You either need a purely expandable loop or some other possibly non expandable but cunning macro. There are expandable loops in the LaTeX kernel. (and you can do what you want with non expandable `\xintFor` macro from package `xinttools`).

Comment: @egreg The multicolumn is used for the whole layout. The question here is just a part of the whole table.

Comment: @jfbu I tried a loop with xinttools, but I get an error, that the parameters of my command are wrong. I think it is because of that I had to use #2 or something. Maybe I get something wrong how and in which context to use this. Maybe you can write a full answer with a working code example in the context I need it (as a usable command with one parameter). Thank you!

Comment: @baghira Perhaps you need to double the `#` but anyhow I don't think it could work (now that I have read your question for real ;-) ). See answer.

Comment: Related Question: [Build tabular content via \foreach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175568/build-tabular-content-via-foreach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with an expandable loop. For some reason most `xinttools` facilities are for inputs of the  `{item1}{item2}{item3}` type ; if one prefers `item1, item2, item3` one needs to apply `\xintCSVtoList` as here in the `\makeRows` command.

I mentioned `\xintFor` in a comment but I had not read closely enough the question (sorry) ... `\multicolumn` is a beast which really wants to be first in its cell (after expansion). Macro `\xintFor` does some (non global) assignments, thus it is not the appropriate tool here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand\makeOneRow [1]{\multicolumn{3}{c}{#1} & \\ }
\newcommand\makeRows [1]{%
    \xintApplyUnbraced {\makeOneRow}{\xintCSVtoList{#1}}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lclr}
    \makeRows{item1, item2, item3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you had wanted the `\multicolumn` in the second cell it would have worked :

```
 \xintFor #1 in {item1, item2, item3}\do
  {& \multicolumn{3}{c}{#1}\\}
```

and if you put this in a  `\newcommand\makeTabularRows` where `#1` will stand for the csv of items, you need to use `\xintFor ##1 in {#1} \do {...}`.