# Tabular with conditional rows based on content

Tags: tables, conditionals, collcell

I would like to define appropriate column types which suppress an entire *row* of a table if *all* of the columns (besides the title column, ie the first column) are empty.  That is, with the `tabular` content as:

```
Label 1 & 62  & 79 \\
Label 2 &     &    \\
Label 3 &     & 31 \\
Label 4 & 45  &    \\
```

I would like to automatically suppress the row with `Label 2`.

#### My Attempt:

I defined a `T` column type at which time it is determined if the prior row is to be typeset via:

```
\newcommand{\TitleColumn}[1]{% We are starting a new row
    %% If there was a previous row that needed to be output, display that now
    \iftoggle{DisplayThisRow}{%
        \PrintTableTokens% Print prior row
        \global\togglefalse{DisplayThisRow}% Assume entire row is empty
    }{%
        %\vspace*{-\baselineskip}% Attempt to fix empty rows.
    }%
    \ResetTableTokens%
    \AddTableTokens{#1}% Start a new row with the row label
}
```

All other columns are of type `L` which sets the boolean `DisplayThisRow` to `true` upon encountering a non-empty cell:

```
\newcommand{\ColumnL}[1]{%
    \AddTableTokens{#1}% <--- Need a leading & here
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{}{% Enable printing of row if non-empty content encoutered
        \global\toggletrue{DisplayThisRow}%
    }%
}
```

My attempt, based on

- [How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165126/4301)
- [Build tabular content via \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175568/4301)

which yields

[image]

may not be the best approach. The current problems with it include:

1. A blank like is output when a row is to be suppressed.
2. The column separators are missing. Including a column separators in the call to `\AddTableTokens{& #1}` in the `\ColumnL` macro leads to

   > Misplaced alignment tab character &.
3. I was expecting a problem in that the last row would not be printed as there was no subsequent `T` column, but for some  bizarre reason, the last row, `Label 4`, is printed first!

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{showframe}

%% This is based on:
%%    https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165126/4301
%%    https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175568/4301
%%
\makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\@MyTempTableTokens}{}%
    \newtoks\@tabtoks
    %%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, in case they are done in \foreach
    \newcommand\AddTableTokens[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
    \newcommand\eAddTableTokens[1]{% Do NOT add a tailing \\ for each line
        \protected@edef\@MyTempTableTokens{#1}%
        \expandafter\AddTableTokens\expandafter{\@MyTempTableTokens  \\}%
    }%
    %%% variable should be operated on always locally or always globally
    \newcommand*\ResetTableTokens{\global\@tabtoks{}}
    \newcommand*\PrintTableTokens{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\ColumnL}[1]{%
    \AddTableTokens{#1}% <--- Need a leading & here
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{}{% Enable printing of row if non-empty content encoutered
        \global\toggletrue{DisplayThisRow}%
    }%
}

\newtoggle{DisplayThisRow}%
\togglefalse{DisplayThisRow}%
\newcommand{\TitleColumn}[1]{% We are starting a new row
    %% If there was a previous row that needed to be output, display that now
    \iftoggle{DisplayThisRow}{%
        \PrintTableTokens% Print prior row
        \global\togglefalse{DisplayThisRow}% Assume entire row is empty
    }{%
        %\vspace*{-\baselineskip}% Attempt to fix empty rows.
    }%
    \ResetTableTokens%
    \AddTableTokens{#1}% Start a new row with the row label
}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\ColumnL}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\collectcell\TitleColumn}X<{\endcollectcell}}


\begin{document}
%\showcols
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}TLL@{}} 
    Label 1 & 62  & 79 \\
    Label 2 &     &    \\
    Label 3 &     & 31 \\
    Label 4 & 45  &    \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

I use `listofitems` package to parse through the `\BODY` of the `tabular`.  For each successive row, I search columns 2-n in search of data other than spaces.  If found, I set `\rowstatus` to `T`.  If the `\rowstatus` ends up `T`, I append the row's tokens to a macro (`\tabdatatoks`) for later use.  Otherwise, I search the [failed] blank row's tokens for an `\hline`.  If found, I also append that to the saved tokens list, even though the row is otherwise blank.

When done searching, I compose the `tabular` using the saved token list.

EDITED to handle additional row separators, such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`, in addition to `\hline`.  Others can be easily added to the line `\setsepchar{\hline||\bottomrule||\toprule}`, with one proviso...the row separator cannot take an argument (e.g., `\cline{1,3}`).

REEDITED to properly handle instances of `\cmidrule(x){x-x}` and now `\cline{x-x}`.  Any row separator that takes arguments other than `\cmidrule` and `\cline` will need extra code added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,environ,booktabs}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{mytab}[2][c]{%
  \setsepchar{\\/&}%
  \readlist\mytabdata{\BODY}%
  \def\tabdatatoks{}%
  \foreachitem\tabrow\in\mytabdata[]{%
    \gdef\rowstatus{F}%
    \foreachitem\tabcol\in\mytabdata[\tabrowcnt]{%
      \ifnum\tabcolcnt=1\relax\else%
        \setsepchar{ }%
        \readlist\mytabcell{\tabcol}%
        \foreachitem\cellpart\in\mytabcell[]{%
          \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\cellpart\relax\else\gdef\rowstatus{T}\fi%
        }%
      \fi%
    }%
    \if T\rowstatus%
%     ADD NONEMPTY ROW DATA TO TOKEN LIST
      \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\tabdatatoks\expandafter{\tabrow\\}%
    \else%
%     FOR EMPTY ROWS, SEARCH FOR AND RETAIN ROW SEPARATOR LINES
      \setsepchar{\hline||\cline||\bottomrule||\midrule||\toprule||\cmidrule}%
      \expandafter\readlist\expandafter\rowsep\expandafter{\tabrow\ }%
      \foreachitem\x\in\rowsep[]{%
        \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\rowsep[]\else%
%         ADD ROW SEPARATOR TO TOKEN LIST
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\g@addto@macro%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tabdatatoks%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\rowsepsep[\xcnt]}%
%         SPECIAL PROVISIONS FOR ROW SEPARATORS WITH ARGUMENTS:
          \checkforsep{\cmidrule}{\getcmidruleargs}%
          \checkforsep{\cline}{\getclineargs}%
        \fi%
      }%
    \fi%
  }%
  \def\tmp{\begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}}\expandafter\tmp\tabdatatoks\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand\checkforsep[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\rowsepsep[\xcnt]#1%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2\rowsep[\numexpr\xcnt+1\relax]\relax\fi%
}
\def\getcmidruleargs(#1)#2#3\relax{\g@addto@macro\tabdatatoks{(#1){#2}}}
\def\getclineargs#1#2\relax{\g@addto@macro\tabdatatoks{{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mytab}{lrr}
\toprule
Label 1 & 62  & 79     \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(r){3-3}
Label 2 &     &        \\
Label 3 &     & 31     \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
Label 4 &     &      \\
Label 5 & 45  & \today \\
\bottomrule
\end{mytab}\bigskip

For comparison, normal tabular:\medskip

\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
Label 1 & 62  & 79     \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(r){3-3}
Label 2 &     &        \\
Label 3 &     & 31     \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
Label 4 &     &      \\
Label 5 & 45  & \today \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks very nice!  Is it easy to expand the detection of `\hline` to include other separators? I was able to include `\bottomrule` by duplicating the lines in the `\else` clause but wondering if there is an easier way. Similarly, I was using `\cmidrule(r){1-2}` and wrapping that in a macro `\newcommand*{\Divider}{\cmidrule(r){1-2}}`, I was able to get it to work by again duplicating the three lines in the `\else` clause to check for `\Divider`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, I've edited to make the process more customizable, but with one exception: it cannot handle row separators that take an argument, such as `\cline{}`.  If that is a big issue, I can give it more thought.

Comment: Separators with parameter is not a big issue as I can just wrap it in a macro. However, it appears to work _without_ requiring further modification. Simply defining `\newcommand*{\Divider}{\cmidrule(r){1-2}}` and using `\Divider` seems to be working. I was expecting to have to add `\Divider` to the list of possible separators, so wondering if I am missing something here? Also, `\cmidrule(r){1-2}` used directly seems to work too!!!! Huh?

Comment: @PeterGrill There is no problem with any row separator, *if it appears in a valid row*.  The issue is *if it appears in a blank row.* (i.e., leading up to "Label 2" in your example).

Comment: Yep, using `\cmidrule(r){1-2}`directly (without defining a separate macro) following `Label 2` seems to work too with this new version.  It didn't in an earlier version.

Comment: @PeterGrill `listofitems` initial parse is on the basis of `\\/&` meaning the "row" data is what falls between successive double backslashes.  Thus, if your `\cmidrule` falls **prior** to (not **following**) Label 2, it will technically be in the same row data as Label 2.  That is when it will be affected.

Comment: Ah, so that was the issue. But, why does an `\hline` _before_ `Labe 2` end up being a `\toprule` style line?

Comment: @PeterGrill My guess is that, when using `booktabs`, don't use `\hline`, but rather `\midrule`.  I am about to post the ultimate fix for the issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill I have provided support for `\cline` as well.