# Input of tablerows via variable

Tags: macros, longtable, variable

The following will work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \\
    5,8 &5,3 &3,4 \\
    8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

However, I want to put the contents of the table in a variable, and as far as I experienced this will not work out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tablerows}{
    5,8 &5,3 &3,4 \\
    8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\
}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
    \caption{Blabla}
    \\
    \tablerows
    8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

It says "Misplaced alignment tab character &. \tablerows"
What am I doing wrong?
And if there is a solution - what is the limitation, how many characters / lines can be put in a variable before it get's too big?

Comment: I have no error message with this code.

Comment: For a more extensible solution on how to build up a table, see [How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165153/4301).  I have been using this for a while and it works great.  A follow-up question, which leads to several reated question is [Tabular with conditional rows based on content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455895/4301.

Comment: @Bernard, does both code examples output the same result when you compile? Maybe a problem of my compilation environment (miktex + TeXstudio)?

Comment: Not exactly, as the second code has one more row. For the rest, they're the same. I compile with MiKTeX too. Maybe try updating if not already done?

Comment: Ok - now it also works for me. Thank you for commenting!