filling a table in a loop
I want to fill a long table in a loop
by condition
if j =1 then the string is entered
if j =0 then the line is not entered
j - changes in a loop
problem with the table
If I set 1 then lines (2) are printed correctly
if I set 0 then they should not be printed - and this does not work
%===============================
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english, russian] {babel} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}    

\begin{longtable}{|p{60pt}|p{40pt}|p{220pt}|}
    \hline
    {date} & {version} & {Changes}\\
    \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{l}%
    {\bf  (continuation) } \\
    \hline
    {date} & {version} & {Changes} \\ \hline
    \endhead
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot    
    %-------------------------------------------------------------
    13.09.2019 & 1 &  initial release \\ \hline %----First line---  
    \newcounter{i}   % line counter
    %------------------------------        
    \def\j{0}
         
    \forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 3}{  
    \ifnum \j > 0
    20.09.2019 & 2 & Text \\ \hline
    \else 
    \fi       }
    %-----------------------------
& & last line \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


Filling tables (not only longtable) using a loop inside the table is always problematic. Instead it is recommended to collect the table tokens in the loop and then use the collection to build the whole table. See, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630957/create-table-with-for-loop-numpoint-loops-and-formula or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165126/277964

Off-topic: You should not use obsolete font command \bf. Use either {\bfseries …} or \textbf{…} instead.
