# Using \pgfplotsinvokeforeach to create rows in a matrix of nodes

Tags: pgfplots, loops

I'm working on a complicated set of figures using the pgfplots package. As part of the figures, I'd like to be able to create a matrix of nodes in which rows are added using a call to `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` or a similar looping command. A minimal working example achieving something very close to what I want is given below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17, filter discard warning=false}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\MakeMatrix}[1]{%
  \matrix (myMatrix) [ matrix of nodes ]
  {
     A \\
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{#1}{
      ##1
    } \\
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \MakeMatrix{B,C,D,E,F}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: compiled LaTeX output]

The document fails to compile, however, if I move the row separator `\\` inside of the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` loop (thus achieving my ultimate goal of one row per loop iteration). I'd like to know if this is achievable with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` (ideal) or a similar approach to looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted a solution from [Build tabular content via \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175568/61460). Minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17, filter discard warning=false}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand*{\MyTempTableTokens}{}%
\makeatletter
  \newtoks\@tabtoks
  %%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
  \newcommand\AddTableTokens[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
  \newcommand\eAddTableTokens[1]{%
    \edef\MyTempTableTokens{#1}%
    \expandafter\AddTableTokens\expandafter{\MyTempTableTokens}%
    }
  %%% variable should always be operated on always locally or always globally
  \newcommand*\ResetTableTokens{\global\@tabtoks{}}
  \newcommand*\PrintTableTokens{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\MakeMatrix}[1]{%

  \ResetTableTokens
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{#1}{
     \eAddTableTokens{ ##1 \\ }
  }

  \matrix (myMatrix) [ matrix of nodes ] {
    A \\
    \PrintTableTokens
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \MakeMatrix{B,C,D,E,F}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: compiled LaTeX output]