# Using \foreach to add rows containing references to pgfplots objects in a matrix of nodes

Tags: pgfplots, foreach, loops

This is a follow-up question to [Using \pgfplotsinvokeforeach to create rows in a matrix of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654492/61460). Consider the minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17, filter discard warning=false}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot {2*x + 1};
  \label{myPlotA}

  \addplot {3*x + 3};
  \label{myPlotB}

  \addplot {x + 3};
  \label{myPlotC}

  \matrix (myMatrix) [ matrix of nodes, at={(4,-5)} ] {
    \foreach\myletter in {A,B,C}{
      \ref{myPlot\myletter} \myletter
    } \\
    %\ref{myPlotA} A \\
    %\ref{myPlotB} B \\
    %\ref{myPlotC} C \\
  };

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As written, the output looks like this
[image]
but I am interested in producing the behavior given in the commented portion, i.e., output that looks like this
[image]
in an automated way using `\foreach` or a similar command. I run into trouble because inserting the `\\` needed to break between matrix rows causes a compilation error inside of the `\foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up a scratch variable first and then expand it to the whole matrix content at once. The scratch variable has to be global because `\foreach` uses a group for every iteration.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot {2*x + 1};
  \label{myPlotA}
  \addplot {3*x + 3};
  \label{myPlotB}
  \addplot {x + 3};
  \label{myPlotC}
  \makeatletter
    \let\@gtempa\@empty
    \foreach\myletter in {A,B,C} {
      \xappto\@gtempa{\noexpand\ref{myPlot\myletter} \myletter\noexpand\\}
    }
    \matrix (myMatrix) [ matrix of nodes, at={(4,-5)} ] {
      \@gtempa
    };
  \makeatother
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, I don't see why you wouldn't just use `pgfplots`' built-in legend capabilities.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
      legend style={
        draw=none,
        at={(axis cs:4,-5)},
        anchor=center,
      },
    ]
  \addplot {2*x + 1};
  \addlegendentry{A}
  \addplot {3*x + 3};
  \addlegendentry{B}
  \addplot {x + 3};
  \addlegendentry{C}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(If you only want to put the legend somewhere in that corner you can just use `legend pos=south east`.)