# Using foreach to add variable number of rows to a bytefield inside a TikZ node? (part 2)

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgffor, bytefield

I am trying to add a variable number of fields to a bytefield, inside a TikZ Node. An earlier question ([Using foreach to add variable number of rows to a bytefield inside a TikZ node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679919/using-foreach-to-add-variable-number-of-rows-to-a-bytefield-inside-a-tikz-node/679923?noredirect=1#comment1687472_679923)) gave helpful hints, but I still don't get it to work. So, here a more detailed example.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% What I want to achieve, written out without loops:
% (inelegant, does not scale to the large number of nodes
% for which I need this)
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node [draw] (a) {a};
  \node [draw] at (6,0) (b) {b};
  
  \node [below=of a] {
    \begin{bytefield}{8}
      \wordbox{1}{Source: b} 
      \\ \wordbox{1}{1} 
      \\ \wordbox{1}{2} 
      \\ \wordbox{1}{3}
    \end{bytefield}
  };

  \node [below=of b] {
    \begin{bytefield}{8}
      \wordbox{1}{Source: a} 
      \\ \wordbox{1}{4} 
      \\ \wordbox{1}{5}
    \end{bytefield}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% What should be a step in the right direction,
% compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679919/using-foreach-to-add-variable-number-of-rows-to-a-bytefield-inside-a-tikz-node/679923?noredirect=1#comment1687472_679923

\begin{tikzpicture}[wordbox/.code={\\\wordbox{1}{#1}}]
  \node {
    \begin{bytefield}{8}
      \wordbox{1}{Source: A} 
      \tikzset{wordbox/.list={1,2,3}}
    \end{bytefield}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}



% How I hope to get it to work, but only get two wordboxes,
% instead of four on the left, three on the right: 
\begin{tikzpicture}[wordbox/.code={\\\wordbox{1}{#1}}]

  \node [draw] (a) {a};
  \node [draw] at (6,0) (b) {b};
  
  \foreach \n/\fields in {a/{1,2,3},b/{4,5}} {
  \node [below=of \n] {
    \begin{bytefield}{8}
      \wordbox{1}{Source: \n}
      \tikzset{wordbox/.list=\fields}
    \end{bytefield}
  };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}


% An alternative with a foreach inside bytefield does not even compile: 
% \begin{tikzpicture}

%   \node [draw] (a) {a};
%   \node [draw] at (6,0) (b) {b};
  
%   \foreach \n/\fields in {a/{1,2,3},b/{4,5}} {
%   \node [below=of \n] {
%     \begin{bytefield}{8}
%       \wordbox{1}{Source: \n}
%       \foreach \f in \fields { \\ \wordbox{1}{\f} }
%     \end{bytefield}
%   };
%   }
% \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Example figures for the three steps see below.

In the last case, it seems that the list handler does not iterate over the fields? Any way to fix that?

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Intermediate step in the right direction?

[image: Intermediate step in the right direction?]

What I get:

[image: What I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just say `/.list=\fields`, the macro `\fields` will be the only element of your list. Internally, this will lead to a loop that looks like

```
\foreach \ELEMENT in {\fields}
```

You need to expand `\fields` at least once before the `.list` handler should evaluate it. Thus, you need

```
\tikzset{wordbox/.list/.expand once=\fields}
```

or

```
\tikzset{wordbox/.list/.expanded=\fields}
```

---

Your second example (with an explicit `\foreach` loop) leads to problems because it will group each iteration. It would be similar to

```
\begin{bytefield}{8}
  \wordbox{1}{Source: \n}
  { \\ \wordbox{1}{1} }
  { \\ \wordbox{1}{2} }
  { \\ \wordbox{1}{3} }
\end{bytefield}
```

which conflicts on how `bytefield` works internally.

If you're not satisfied with `.list` (which uses PGFFor's `\foreach` internally and would allow the `...` syntax) you could use for example `\int_step_inline:nnn` used as such:

```
% Preamble
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ForeachInline}{}{\int_step_inline:nnn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Document
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (a) {a};
\node [draw] at (6,0) (b) {b};

\foreach \n/\st/\en in {a/1/3, b/4/5} {
  \node [below=of \n] {
    \begin{bytefield}{8}
      \wordbox{1}{Source: \n}
      \ForeachInline{\st}{\en}{ \\ \wordbox{1}{##1} }
    \end{bytefield}
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I swear, someday I will understand the expand mechanism :-).