# How can I use \foreach in math environments?

Tags: math-mode, align, loops, foreach, pgffor

I'm looking for a way to generate in a loop the rows of an `align` environment, or `IEEEeqnarray` or some such thing. I can see that `\foreach` works in math mode (inside `\[ \]` e.g.), but something like this

```
\begin{align*}
   \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
   {
      V_\i & = 12345
   }
\end{align*}
```

fails with

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> }
            $}\ifmeasuring@ \savefieldlength@ \fi \set@field \endtemplate
l.161 \end{align*}
```

Can I make this work without much hassle?

Comment: have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/how-do-i-use-the-ampersand-inside-a-foreach-or-conditional-or-other-group-e

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `\foreach` is evaluated in a group to prevent overwriting of the contents of the iteration variable.  TeX does not allow alignment tabs to grouped in alignments, hence the error.  You could use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` from the `pgfplots` package to circumvent that restriction.  Also you might want to have a look at the formatting again.  The output doesn't look like this is desired.  You should also brace the index or you will be surprised as you hit two digit indices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,5}
   {
      V_{\i} & = 12345
   }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Probably a ``\\`` token was missing in the original.

Comment: @egreg Most probably, yes, but I'll leave that as an exercise for OP.

Comment: Yes, the format is not intended, but I did not bother fixing it before getting it to work at all.