# \pgfplotsforeachungrouped: how to escape & and \\

Tags: matrices, loops, foreach, branching

Disclaimer: I've barely started to learn LaTeX so bear with me.

Problem: I use a lot of matrices like this

[image: Matrix]

Which I absolutely hate to code manually. Obvious solution would be a nested for loop, something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \m in {1,...,3}
{
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \n in {1,...,3}
  {
    a_{\m,\n} &
  } \\
}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

(I got the idea to use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284268/106612)). Unfortunately there are two problems:

1. The `&` and `\\` tokens break the compilation process and pdfLaTeX barfs a bunch of `Undefined control sequence` errors.
2. Even if this works, I'll still need a way to disable these tokens at the last iteration, otherwise I'll end up with one empty column and one empty row. (Or maybe even worse because the last empty row won't contain proper amount of `&`'s).

If there is a proper way of constructing such matrices it will suffice, although I'll still be curious about whether if-branching inside a for-loop is possible.

Comment: Use `\newline` or `\hfill \break` not the double backslash.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432274/use-array-meaningful-ampersand-to-change-column-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the problem with this is timing: a loop cannot start in a cell and end in another one.

Here's an `expl3` implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\symbolicmatrix}{O{#2}mm}
 {% #1 = optional number of rows (default square)
  % #2 = number of columns
  % #3 = symbol to repeat
  \scumcoder_matrix:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__scumcoder_matrix_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scumcoder_matrix:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__scumcoder_matrix_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #2 - 1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__scumcoder_matrix_body_tl { #3\sb{##1 ####1} & }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__scumcoder_matrix_body_tl { #3\sb{##1 #2} \\ }
   }
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \tl_use:N \l__scumcoder_matrix_body_tl
  \end{bmatrix}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\bm{\varepsilon} \\
\dot{\bm{\varepsilon}} \\
\bm{\rho}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\symbolicmatrix{3}{\mathbf{F}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\bm{\varepsilon} \\
\dot{\bm{\varepsilon}} \\
\bm{\rho}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
\symbolicmatrix[2]{4}{a}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome as always. (Also, reading the `xparse` documentation was like opening a whole new world).

Answer (score 1):

As it often happens, this is a textbook example of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): I asked about pgf loops, while what I really needed was matrix generation.

2.5 years later I found the *proper* answer to my (wrong) question: the `physics` package.

```
\begin{equation*}
\mqty{\xmat*{F}{3}{3}}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

---

[UPD 2023-11-19] aaand now I'm painfully [migrating away](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471532) from this package. If you are reading this and considering following my footsteps, don't.

Comment: Sign me up. After more than 8 years of using latex, you pointed out this awesome package to me.

Comment: @Diaa might be [not so awesome](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471532) after all

Comment: @ScumCoder I decidedly concur with your last comment

Comment: @ScumCoder aaaand here I go