# Big Boxed equation with title using tcolorbox

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, boxes

I currently have this command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\deq}{omo}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback = blizzardblue!30!white,
    colframe = white,
  ]
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
  \begin{flalign}
    \IfValueT{#1}{\text{\Emph{#1}}} && #2 &&
  \end{flalign}
  \IfValueT{#3}{\emph{#3}}
  \end{tcolorbox}\noindent
}
```

and this code:

```
\deq[Equation's title]{pV = nRT}
```

that produces

[image]

I'm looking for a way to improve that command to be able to write more than 1 equation. For example, with this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[italicdiff]{physics}
\usepackage[scr = rsfso]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable, hooks, theorems}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blizzardblue}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback = blizzardblue!30!white,
    colframe = white]
    \begin{gather}
        \begin{align}
            \qty(\pdv{T}{V})_S &= -\qty(\pdv{p}{S})_V \\
            \qty(\pdv{T}{p})_S &= +\qty(\pdv{V}{S})_p \\
            \qty(\pdv{S}{V})_T &= +\qty(\pdv{p}{T})_V \\
            \qty(\pdv{S}{p})_T &= -\qty(\pdv{V}{T})_p
    \end{align}
    \end{gather}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to be able to produce this (edited figure):

[image]

for any number of equations. Of course, I'm able to use `tcolorbox` environment and `gather` / `equation` environment to write something like that but I can't place -- in the right place -- the equation title. The "right place" is maximally separated (and automatically) from the equations but also centered vertically to all the equations (and of the tcolorbox environment).

The ideal answer to this question would be a new command for N equations with an optional title (which must be centered vertically and maximally separated from the equations). Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Doesn't the manual of tcolorbox provide an example how to incorporate the title inside a box without defining a new command?

Comment: Yes, there is and I know how but it doesn't fit for me that kind of title. I've rewrote the question. Sorry for my bad writing

Comment: Your code don't compile. You have forgot to add the **tcolorbox** package and the package (or the definition) which define the color "blizzardblue".

Comment: Can you specify the expected behavior of the equations when the "Equation title" is very long? In your edited figure, equations are horizontally centered, but when the Equation title is long, would you a narrow gap between the Equation title and the equations, and a large gap between the equations and the labels?

Comment: When the "Equation's title" is too long, the space between the equation and it's number (\theequation) gets shorter (that's what happens and what I would expect). But, the titles I'm using are shorts, so there wouldn't be a case of "title too long"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. I have replaced the call to the package **physics** to the call to the package **derivative** because **physics** is not recommanded (see [Alternatives to the physics package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471532/alternatives-to-the-physics-package;) by the way, there is a new package called **physics2** which replace some functionalitys of *physics* package, see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics2 and the document http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/physics2/doc/physics2-legacy.pdf for switching from *physics* to *physics2*). It isn't need to load **xcolor** because **tcolorbox** load it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{derivative}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{blizzardblue}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2][]{%
\tcbsidebyside[sidebyside adapt=left, sidebyside gap=5mm,colback = blizzardblue!30!white,colframe = blizzardblue!30!white
]{%
 #1
}{%
\begin{gather}
    \begin{align}
        #2      
    \end{align}
\end{gather}
}
}

\begin{document}

\mybox[Equation title]{%
\pdv{T}{V}_S &= -\pdv{p}{S}_V \\
\pdv{T}{p}_S &= +\pdv{V}{S}_p \\
\pdv{S}{V}_T &= +\pdv{p}{T}_V \\
\pdv{S}{p}_T &= -\pdv{V}{T}_p
}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: any chance that there's something missing or anything I may not have? It is not compiling `Undefined control sequence. \\mybox [#1]#2->\tcbsidebyside`. I only have what you wrote and it's not compiling

Comment: I using Tex Live 2022 and pdflatex for the compilation. `\tcbsidebyside` is from 2015-11-20 version of **tcolorbox** (page 138, section 6.2 of the documentation at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

Comment: According this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55473#55473) (MikTex) I have all my tex packages updated :(. Any idea where can I read how to fix this and use your answer?

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` in your preamble (e.g. right after `\documentclass{article}`)?  Then see your .log file to find the version of **tcolorbox** used (in my case, I read: *tcolorbox.sty    2022/06/24 version 5.1.1 text color boxes*).

Comment: Yep, I have an older version: 2022/01/07 version 5.0.2, even though miktex says that there's not any update available

Comment: Does the code on page 138 of http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf works? Be careful when you copy/paste the code from the pdf viewer, as some line can be pasted after a `%` sign (for me, the line `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `}{%`). Don't forget to load the *skins* library (`\tcbuselibrary{skins}`) and the `lipsum` and `tikz`package).

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The `\tcbsidebyside` causes the error I believe

Comment: Can you consider installing Tex Live or using Overleaf instead of MikTeX? Or create a new question (perhaps MikTeX has broken the installation of **tcolorbox**. It's also strange that you can't install the latest version of **tcolorbox**). Try also to compile the file `tcolorbox-example.tex` from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox to see if there are another things broken in **tcolorbox** installed by MikTeX.