# How to get the value of counter in pgffor while using \expandafter

Tags: expansion, pgffor

I looked into [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165149/4035) and tried to improve it. My goal is to get this table:

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
```

But instead I get this:

```
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \i in {1,...,3} {%
  \addtabtoks{\i \\\hline}
}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | }
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I think, it's caused by `\expandafter`, but I don't know, how to fix it.

Comment: I added code to my answer for coping with your problem and also the one in your other question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to add the expansion of `\i` not the token `\i` so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \i in {1,...,3} {%
  \expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\i \\\hline}%
}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | }
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain, how does it work?

Comment: @user4035 your code added `\i` three times producing a token register `\i\\ \i\\ \i\\ `  so when you used it you got the final value of `\i` three times. This uses `\expandafter` to expand `\i` before adding it to the register so the register holds `1\\ 2\\ 3\\ ` so when you use it you get 1 2 3

Comment: Can you look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320998/value-of-counter-from-pgffor-in-a-complex-example? I did something wrong.