# Value of counter from pgffor in a complex example

Tags: macros, expansion, pgffor

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320994/4035) I learned how to print rows into 1 column table using pgffor:

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
```

Code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \i in {1,...,3} {%
  \expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\i \\\hline}%
}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | }
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Then I wanted to improve it and get a table with 2 columns:

```
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
```

Using both macro and simple expansion, I created this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\myline}[1]{
  #1 & #1\\ \hline
}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%1-st attempt
\resettabtoks
\foreach \i in {1,...,3} {%
  \expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\i & \i\\\hline}
}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
\end{tabular}

%2-nd attempt
\resettabtoks
\foreach \i in {1,...,3} {%
  \expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\myline{\i}}
}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

1-st attempt gives:

```
| 1 | l |
| 2 | l |
| 3 | l |
```

2-nd attempt gives:

```
| l | l |
| l | l |
| l | l |
```

Why is "l" shown instead of \i value? And how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the updated code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165149/4035 you can do

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
%%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
\newcommand\addtabtoks[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    % no index, just append the second argument
    \global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#2}%
  \else
    % we assume the second argument is a one parameter macro
    \global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\@tabtoks\expandafter#2\expandafter{#1}}%
  \fi
}
%%% variable should always be operated on always locally or always globally
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\myline}[1]{%
  #1 & #1 \\
}


\begin{document}

\resettabtoks
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{%
  \addtabtoks[\i]{\myline}%
}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 \expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\i & \i\\\hline}
```

only expands the first `\i` so you are adding `1&\i` then `2&\i` then `3&\i` so the second column gets the same value at each iteration.

You could use

```
  \edef\x{\noexpand\addtabtoks{\i & \i\noexpand\\ \noexpand\hline}}
  \x
```

To fully expand both instances of `\i` before adding to the token register.