what is so special about 199 rows in tex4ht? After 199 rows, tex4ht do not add closing \hline
in TL 2024, I have long table. When there are 199 rows or more, the table generated by tex4ht loses the closing \hline at the bottom of the table.
Here is screen shot of the end of a 198 rows table

Here is screen shot of the end of a 199 rows table (notice, missing final hline)

Here is MWE to produce the above
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xinttools}

%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/how-do-i-use-the-ampersand-inside-a-foreach-or-conditional-or-other-group-e
%for loop code below
\newcommand{\nRows}{199} %change this to change number of rows

\begin{document}

\chapter{long tables}
\section{Problems not solved}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.35in}|p{2.6in}|p{2.2in}|p{.4in}|p{.4in}|}\hline
\# & ODE&  CAS classification& Maple solved? &  Mma solved? \\\hline
 \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\nRows}}
    \do
    {  #1&B&C&D&E \\\hline }
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

Command used is
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug index.tex 'mathjax,htm'

TL 2024 on Linux Ubuntu
Why this happens and how to correct it?   This only affect tex4ht. No such problem in pdf.
tex4ht report 640

I cannot reproduce this issue. I see all hlines in both Firefox and Chromium, even if I change the number of \nRows to 400.

@michal.h21 This is on new Linux, under WSL 2.0. Just installed TL today. May be there was some changes in latest texlive?  I'll add link to the log file generated also now. Need few minutes.

There is nothing in the log file. The HTML code and CSS would be more interesing.

@michal.h21 fyi, added links above. I've also checked this in firefox and Brave browsers. Both show the missing hline after 199 rows.

I am using windows 10 as desktop. But compile on Linux.

Thanks, I can see that there is a missing <tr class="hline> in your HTML. I see that you have current versions of longtable.4ht and html4.4ht so that shouldn't be a problem. Could you try the -f html5-common_domfilters option? This should disable make4ht DOM filters and create some spurious vertical lines at the bottom of the table, but will tell us if the last hline is here.

Interestingly, when I run the code I can't reproduce the issue of the missing hline, but I have a different issue where the vertical line overshoots, see https://i.sstatic.net/EfLIi7ZP.png, both for 198 and 199 lines. In the html the table ends with a <tr class='hline'> followed by three additional <tr id='TBL-1-20x-' rows (for x=2,3,4), the first two stating they are from <!-- l. 20 --> which is \end{longtable} in the .tex and having only one <td></td>, the last one without a l. xx comment and with four <td></td> pairs, each row adding a few pixels to the overshoot.

My version of TeX Live/tex4ht is not fully up to date (TL2023) but it might be relevant for the latest versions as well to figure out what causes this html output.

My guess would be this is related to LTchunksize having a default value of 200

@Marijn the issue of overshoots should be fixed in the curent TeX Live, it is removed by make4ht DOM filters.

@michal.h21 tried with -f html5-common_domfilters and now the closing html shows OK, but with extra vertical lines. So it seems to be related to the domfilters? I've put link above to the new output and screen shot

Ah, I've found that I had older version of make4ht on my system. I can reproduce it now.

@michal.h21 good to know you can reproduce the issue now. Thanks.

You have been on this site long enough to know not to edit solutions in to the question. It messes up the question and answer format

@DavidCarlisle I really have no idea what you mean. I did not edit solution given. If you mean I should not add more information to my question afterwords, I now removed all that information I added after initial quesiton. Hopefully this is what you meant.

make4ht post-processes tables to remove some spurious lines that are inserted at the end of tables:

It seems that at 200th row longtable changes the output for the \hline, and it no longer produces these extra lines, but make4ht still removes it.
Here is the fixed version of the DOM filter, which will remove only the spurious lines, not the correct \hline. Save it as make4ht-tablerows.lua in the domfilters subdirectory of the directory with your document:
local log = logging.new ("tablerows")
return function(dom)
  local has_child_elements = function(child)
    -- detect if the element contains child elements
    local child_elements = 0
    local children = child:get_children()
    local last_child_pos
    for pos, el in ipairs(children) do
      last_child_pos = pos
      local step = el:is_element() and 1 or 0
      -- log:info("element name", el._name)
      child_elements = child_elements + step
    end
    -- longtable has <td><p></p></td> inside empty rows, we regard them as empty
    if child_elements == 1 and children[last_child_pos]:get_element_name() == "p" and child:get_text():gsub("%s", "") == "" then
      child_elements = 0
    end
    return child_elements > 0
  end
  local is_empty_row = function(row)
    local not_empty = false
    local element_count = 0
    -- ignore hline rows
    local row_class = row:get_attribute("class") 
    if row_class == "hline" or row_class == "cline" then return false end
    -- detect if the row contain only one empty child
    for _,child in ipairs(row:get_children() or {}) do
      if child:is_element() then 
        element_count = element_count + 1
        -- empty rows contain only one element, it is not empty otherwise
        if element_count > 1 or has_child_elements(child) then return false end

        -- detect if it contains only whitespace
        not_empty = child:get_text():gsub("%s","") ~= "" or not_empty
      end
    end
    -- print("element count", element_count, not_empty)
    return element_count == 1 and not_empty == false
  end
  local is_not_styled = function(row, css)
    -- get the id attribute and escape it, so it can be used in regexp
    local id = row:get_attribute("id")
    if not id then return true end -- no styling without id
    local search_term = "%#" .. id:gsub("%-", "%%-")
    -- if the CSS file contains the row id (<td> elements can also have id
    -- that matches this pattern, so we should keep the row if we match them too)
    return not css:match(search_term)
  end
  local hline_hr = function(row)
    -- remove <hr> elements from "hline" rows
    for _, hr in ipairs(row:query_selector(".hline hr")) do
      hr:remove_node()
    end
  end
  local longtable_last_row = function(tbl)
    print("lontable last row")
    -- longtable contains last row of empty cells
    local rows= tbl:query_selector("tr")
    local last_row = rows[#rows]
    if not last_row or last_row:get_attribute("class") == "hline" then return end
    for _, cell in ipairs(last_row:query_selector("td")) do
      -- loop over cells in the last row a and detect that they are empty. break processing if they are not.
      if has_child_elements(cell) or not cell:get_text():match("^%s*$") then
        return 
      end
    end
    last_row:remove_node()
  end
  local load_css_files = function()
    -- the empty rows can be styled using CSS, for example configuration for 
    -- Booktabs does that. We shouldn't remove such rows.
    local cssfiles = {}
    for  _, link in ipairs(dom:query_selector("head link")) do
      local src = link:get_attribute("href")
      if src then
        local f = io.open(src, "r")
        if f then
          local contents = f:read("*all")
          f:close()
          table.insert(cssfiles, contents)
        end
      end
    end
    return table.concat(cssfiles, "\n")
  end
  local css = load_css_files()
  for _, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
    -- find the empty rows
    local rows = tbl:query_selector("tr")
    for count, row in ipairs(rows) do
      if is_empty_row(row) and is_not_styled(row, css) then row:remove_node() end
      hline_hr(row)
    end
    if tbl:get_attribute("class") and tbl:get_attribute("class"):match("longtable")
    then
      longtable_last_row(tbl)
    end
  end
  return dom
end


With this version, you will get this result:


Thanks for the fix Michal !
