# Generate table using the foreach command from pgffor

Tags: foreach

I want to generate a table from a list. However for some reason it fails to work. I searched:

[PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla)

[Copy table row n times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62177/copy-table-row-n-times/62181#62181)

and tried different solutions but none of them work for some reason :(

```
\documentclass{minimal}                                                         
\usepackage{tikz}                                                               
\begin{document}                                                                
  \begin{tabular}{ll}                                                             
    \foreach \x/\y in {-2/a,-1/b,1/c,2/d} {%                                        
      \edef\temp{\noexpand \x & \y \\ }%                                            
      \temp                                                                         
    }%                                                                              
  \end{tabular}                                                                   
\end{document}
```

Edit...

Also tried [How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/how-do-i-use-the-ampersand-inside-a-foreach-or-conditional-or-other-group-e)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand\eaddtabtoks[1]{\edef\mytmp{#1}\expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\mytmp}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \x/\y in {-2/a,-1/b,1/c,2/d}{%
  \eaddtabtoks{\x & \y \\ }%
}% 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\printtabtoks
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Does not seem to work.

> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
>   ! Undefined control sequence. \  ->\let \reserved@e 
>                          \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv... l.17 }
>         % ?

Comment: This has appeared several times, I believe.

Comment: Thats true. But why doesn't my code work then? I tried both solutions in the topics to which I link.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/how-do-i-use-the-ampersand-inside-a-foreach-or-conditional-or-other-group-e

Comment: @egreg tried. Does not seem to work...

Comment: You have to say ``\protect\\`` inside `\eaddtabtoks`

Comment: @egreg `\eaddtabtoks{\x & \y \protect\\ }%` does not help. But I got it working. I changed to code to... `\eaddtabtoks{\x} \addtabtoks{&} \eaddtabtoks{\y} \addtabtoks{\\}`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind changing loops and a bit syntax for that specific task, there are other choices such as `\xintForpair`, naturally not having all the nice functionalities of `\foreach`, but having some others.

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}% (for other things)
\usepackage{xinttools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \xintForpair #1#2 in {(-2,a),(-1,b),(1,c),(2,d)}\do
     {#1&#2\\}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: generated table]