# Automatic table creation from a list

Tags: tables, macros, foreach

I want to build a table form a list (using `pgffor` package):

```
\newcommand{\tablecontent}{
    \foreach \theproduct in \productlist {                                                     
        \getproductcount{\theproduct} &                                                          
        \getproductdescr{\theproduct} &                                                          
        \getproductprice{\theproduct}\\\hline                                                    
    }
}
```

And then use it to create a table like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c}
     .... \\% title row
     \tablecontent
     .... \\% total row
\end{tabularx}
```

But I have the following error:
`Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`

Comment: This can't work this way, because `\foreach` can't operate beyond `table cells' which form a TeX group

Comment: Hi, welcome. There have been several questions here on the site about using loops to create tables before, if you search a bit perhaps you can find something useful.

Comment: If you have is .csv list, you can make a table with `csvsimple` or `datatool` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this previous [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180032/142703).

I found a solution to my problem, by using another loop iterator form `xintootls`.
Note that `\xintFor` doesn't allow usage of `\edef`, but works in `tabular` environment.

```
\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcommand{\printproducts}{
    \xintFor ##1 in {\productlist} \do{
        \getproductcount{##1} &
        \getproductdescr{##1} &
        \getproductprice{##1}\\\hline
    }
}
```