# Insert loop inside table?

Tags: tables, loops

1- I want to make a table  with n number of rows ?

my  wrong code

```
\newcommand{\xx}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline

\newcount\fooo
\fooo=10
\loop


11 & 12 & 13\\
\hline


\advance \fooo -1
\ifnum \fooo>0
\repeat 

\end{tabular}
}
```

I want the result like that using loop or any command
[image: i want the result like that using loop or any command]

2- `\def\abc{dd}` create one value

I want command create multiple values

like 
`\def`-multiple  `\abc {dd,cc,vv,mm}`

---

now i am using this code

`\foreach \x in {1,...,\nRows} {\addtabtoks{ \abc(\x) & yyy & yyy \\\hline}}`

the desired command is `\abc(\x)`  or `\abc(2)`
 first loop type the first value of `\abc` 
 second loop type the second value of `\abc`  and so on

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen [How do I use the ampersand (&) inside a foreach or conditional (or other group/environment) when building tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165126), [How to programmatically make tabular rows using `\whiledo` ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7590), and [Copy table row n times](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62177), for example?

Comment: @cmhughes thanks alot im trying to use it now

Comment: I do not understand, what `\def\abc{dd}` should do? Print out a cell content and `\def\abc{dd,cc,vv,mm}` the contents of 4 cells forming a table row?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Yes exactly

Comment: @user286653: Alright, but does `\def\abc{dd}` etc. change within a table or should all rows look alike as in the table screenshot?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no, every row contains different value or string that all are stored in \abc

Comment: @user286653: Well, and how should the content change from one row to the next one? It must be computable within a loop, or in a other words: How do you 'feed' the macro `\abc` while advancing through the rows

Comment: @user286653 Why do you need so? I mean can you explain your exact situation?

Comment: Generating tables with computed content is basically no problem, but with 'arbitray' content, however, if the content comes from a file etc, this is different.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry if i don't explain enough --- 
 \foreach \x in {1,...,\nRows}
{\addtabtoks{ \abs(\x)  & yyy  & yyy  \\\hline}} ---  where \abs(\x) first loop type the first value of \abc ---- second loop type the second value of \abc --and so on ****the exact case i'm trying to make automated latex code for describing different communication system blocks so the table for inputs and outputs and the same inputs and outputs used for drawing shapes and labeling this shape **sorry for my bad English

Comment: Please update your question with the explanation from your comment.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no i dont use a file as a input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table is implemented by `\halign` primitive where groups are allocated in cells, expansion process and scanning parameters of macros is somewhat more complicated in order to coordinate them with replacing declaration data for cells. This is reason why it is no good idea to do calculations and complicated macro expansion inside and across cells. It is possible but you have to know `\halign` behavior in detail and you need to know exactly what you and TeX are doing.

But more simple solution is possible. You can prepare `\tabledata` before table is processed. This work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcount\fooo
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\begin{document}

\def\tabledata{} \fooo=10
\loop
   \addto\tabledata{11 & 12 & 13\\
                    \hline}
   \advance \fooo -1
   \ifnum \fooo>0
\repeat 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   \tabledata
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

When you need to insert something what depends on the loop variable, then you have to expand it inside the loop. But other fragile macros cannot be expanded. For example you need to insert the value of loop variable. Then you can do it by this:

```
   \edef\tabline{\the\fooo & 12 & 13}
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledata\expandafter{\tabline \\ \hline}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a `LaTeX` solution, with a `\forloop` from `forloop` package. 
It builds a tabular array with a command `\maketablerows{number_of_rows}{rowcontent}`, where rowcontent is suspected to hold the values for the cells in a row, either direct or via a command.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{forloop}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%



\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{column@@counter}
\newcounter{row@@counter}

\newcounter{inner@@counter}%


\edef\t@@blerow{}%
\edef\t@@blerowtemp{}%

\newrobustcmd{\singletablerow}[3]{%
#1  & #2 & #3 
}%



\newrobustcmd{\maketablerows}[2]{%
\setcounter{row@@counter}{0}%
\forloop{row@@counter}{0}{\number\value{row@@counter} < #1}{%
\setcounter{inner@@counter}{\number\value{row@@counter}}%
\stepcounter{inner@@counter}%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{inner@@counter}}{#1}{%
#2% 
}{%
#2 \tabularnewline%
%\hline
}%
}%
}%

\begin{tabular}{lll}
%\hline%
\maketablerows{10}{\singletablerow{11}{12}{13}}%
\tabularnewline%
%\hline%
\end{tabular}

\makeatother


\end{document}
```