# new table environment based on ltablex's tabularx

Tags: environments, ltablex

I defined a new environment for some custom tables (to not have to repeat the header and column definitions etc. again and again).

```
\newenvironment{mytable}{
  \noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|} 
    \hline 
    \bf Col 1 & \bf Col 2 & \bf Col 3 \\ 
    \hline
}{%
  \endtabularx
}
```

It's based on tabularx (for the variable size `X` column) and should be able to span multiple pages. There's the package [`ltablex`](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ltablex/) which can do this for a tabularx environment. (See the `tabularx` in my example below, you can comment out the `mytable`).

However, I am receiving the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{mytable} on input line 26 ended by \end{tabularx}.
```

I assume this comes from the redefinition of `\TX@endtabularx` in `ltablex.sty` where it has the following code snippet:

```
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
   \end{tabularx}
```

Is it possible to use a "longtable tabularx" as a new environment?

Example to try out:

```
\documentclass{article}
% filling table with for, relentlessy copied from 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183756/51583
% extremely shortened, see address for more explanations
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}\def\tabledata{}
\newcount\n\n=1\loop\advance\n by1\addto\tabledata{Lorem&Ipsum&XCell\\}
  \ifnum\n<100\repeat

% package and new environment
\usepackage{ltablex}
\newenvironment{mytable}{%
  \noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|} 
    \hline 
    \bf Col 1 & \bf Col 2 & \bf Col 3 \\ 
    \hline
}{%
  \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}

% working tabularx
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
  \tabledata
\end{tabularx}

% not working mytable
\begin{mytable}
  \tabledata
  \hline
\end{mytable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is to do with the way `tabularx` deals with its argument.  The package `environ` provides a work around for such situations.  Instead of `\newenvironment` you say

```
\NewEnviron{myenv}{start code
   \BODY
   end code}
```

Then

```
\begin{myenv}
  mybody
\end{myenv}
```

will run the contents of `myenv` with `\BODY` replaced by `mybody`.  In your case the relevant definition is

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{mytable}{%
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|} 
    \hline 
    \bf Col 1 & \bf Col 2 & \bf Col 3 \\ 
    \hline
  \BODY
\end{tabularx}
}
```

And a complete file is

```
\documentclass{article}
% filling table with for, relentlessy copied from 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183756/51583
% extremely shortened, see address for more explanations
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}\def\tabledata{}
\newcount\n\n=1\loop\advance\n by1\addto\tabledata{Lorem&Ipsum&XCell\\}
  \ifnum\n<100\repeat

% package and new environment
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{mytable}{%
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|} 
    \hline 
    \bf Col 1 & \bf Col 2 & \bf Col 3 \\ 
    \hline
  \BODY
\end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

% working tabularx
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
  \tabledata
\end{tabularx}

% working mytable
\begin{mytable}
  \tabledata
  \hline
\end{mytable}

\end{document}
```