# ltablex and NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: environments, xparse, ltxtable

I'm trying to wrap long `tabularx` tables from `ltablex` into a new environment (which would do more stuff, but not in the mwe below). However, this gives me an error

```
\begin{wraptable} on input line 15 ended by \end{tabularx}.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wraptable}{}{\tabularx{\linewidth}{XX}}{\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{wraptable}
    foo & bar\\
\end{wraptable}

\end{document}
```

The question [new table environment based on ltablex's tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208850/new-table-environment-based-on-ltablexs-tabularx) deals with the case of `\newenvironment` using the `environ` package. How do I work around this error for `\NewDocumentEnvironment`?

Comment: The work around is the same, use environ, because the problem is still the same, tabularx's behaviour…

Comment: The error vanishes if I change `\end{tabularx}` in the definition of `\TX@endtabularx` with `\endtabularx\endgroup`, but I don't know whether this has side effects.

Comment: @TeXnician Do you mean something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172398/collecting-environment-content-with-support-for-xparse-arguments?