# Generate simple table (with foreach?)

Tags: tabularx, multirow, foreach

I'm trying to generate a simple empty table with \foreach but somehow it doesn't work due to the following error:

> ! Missing \endgroup inserted.
>
> \endgroup
> l.13 ^^I^^I^^I}
> I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
> (See the  above.)

**How can I generate a table?**

My code is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
    \textbf{\#}&        \textbf{First name}     &       \textbf{Last name}      \\\hline\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{1}      &&\\        &&      \\\hline
    \foreach \x in {2,3,...,25}{
        \multirow{2}{*}{\x}     &&\\        &&      \\\hline
        }
    \end{tabular}   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183740/insert-loop-inside-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\foreach` cannot straddle table cells.

Here's a version that works.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makerows}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of lines, #2 = template
  \cs_gset_protected:Nn \__lownds_makerow:n { #2 }
  \int_step_function:nN { #1 } \__lownds_makerow:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lownds_makerow:n {} % initialize
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|w{c}{10em}|w{c}{10em}|}
\hline
\textbf{\#} & \textbf{First name} & \textbf{Last name} \\
\hline
\makerows{10}{#1 & \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & \\ \hline}
\end{tabular}   
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

No need to complicate things with `\multirow`. You can decide for different widths of the cells and the number of rows. The idea is that `\int_step_function:nN` delivers its result in one swoop, so the `&` and `\\` are processed after the whole table contents has been generated. The setting of the auxiliary function `\__lownds_makerow:n` has to be global so it survives the implicit grouping of table cells.

A variation for deciding the starting point.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makerows}{O{1}mm}
 {% #1 = optional starting point, #2 = last number, #3 = template
  \cs_gset_protected:Nn \__lownds_makerow:n { #3 }
  \int_step_function:nnnN { #1 } { 1 } { #2 } \__lownds_makerow:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lownds_makerow:n {} % initialize
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|w{c}{10em}|w{c}{10em}|}
\hline
\textbf{\#} & \textbf{First name} & \textbf{Last name} \\
\hline
\makerows{10}{#1 & \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & \\ \hline }
\end{tabular}
    
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|w{c}{10em}|w{c}{10em}|}
\hline
\textbf{\#} & \textbf{First name} & \textbf{Last name} \\
\hline
\makerows[11]{20}{#1 & \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & \\ \hline }
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also consider `longtable`.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. I also like the w{c}{10em} of the tabular as well as avoiding the multicolumns. Later on, I'm gonna spend some time figuring out what is (exactly) happening. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Additional question that pops up: how can I make the same table on a next page with numbering 11 up to 20?

Comment: @RobertLownds See edit

Comment: Lovely! This works perfect. I'll give longtable a reas as well.