# LaTeX: table with variable number of lines

Tags: tables

In LaTeX, I can do this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{5ex}|p{5ex}|}\hline
  & \\ \hline
  & \\ \hline
  & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

But I cannot get a variable number of blank lines this way

```
\newcommand{\mytable}[1]{
  \begin{tabular}{|p{5ex}|p{5ex}|}\hline
    \multido{}{#1}{%
      &\\\hline
    }% multido
  \end{tabular}
}% mytable
\mytable{10}
```

or with a counter, even without a command \mytable

```
\newcounter{count}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5ex}|p{5ex}|}\hline
\whiledo{\value{count}<5}{%
  & \\ \hline
  \stepcounter{count}
}% whiledo
\end{tabular}
```

Does anybody know why this doesn't work?

Indeed, it is a duplicate of 'copy table row n times'. That is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: Related (if not duplicate) question: [Copy table row n times](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62177); also [problem with using loop inside the tabular environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50296)