# How to make a blank table covering the whole page?

Tags: tables, nicematrix

[image]

How can I make a table like that? Is there a way that the rows adjust themselves automatically?
I need it for a worksheet at school.

Comment: insert in one of the empty cells  a rule of a height (downwards) equal to the remaining vertical space in the page, and width 0pt.

Comment: Are you concerned about the width or the height of the table -- or both? Please advise.

Comment: What exactly does "the rows adjust themselves automatically" refer to? Do you know the required height of your table in advance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assumed that by full page you mean the text area of the page.

The command `\blankrows{<nn>}` adds `nn` blank rows. (From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62178/161015)

The exact number of blank rows  to fill the page depends on the paper size and the layout of the page. In this case is 43.

The package `nicematrix` provides the command `\Block` that replaces `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`, and also allows the use of `\\` inside.

`\Block{}{Lernbereich \\ \scriptsize (Sprechen, Grammatik, \\ \scriptsize Lesen, \dots{})}` defines a 1x1 cell with three lines, the last two with a smaller font.

The column type `P{<number>}` sets the width of the columns in fractions of `\textwidth`, with all five columns adding one `\textwidth`.

**30 rows, showing the margins**

[image: p30x]

**43 rows, full page**

[image: fx]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}% needed <<<<  
\usepackage{nicematrix}% needed <<<<

\usepackage{amssymb} % checkmark    

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62178/161015
\newcommand{\blankrows}[1]{%
    \def\temp{}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {%
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp  & & &  & \\}%
    }%
    \temp}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show margins

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\sffamily\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
        
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{|P{0.2}|P{0.3}|P{0.2}|P{0.2}|P{0.1}|}
    \hline
    Datum & \Block{}{Lernbereich \\ \scriptsize (Sprechen, Grammatik, \\ \scriptsize Lesen, \dots{})} & Thema & Material & \LARGE\color{green}\checkmark  \\
    \hline
    \blankrows{30}  % add rows
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

**Alternative solution**, following Bernard's comment: put an invisible rule with a height to reach the bottom of the text area. In this case `0.925\textheight`. The code is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}% needed <<<<    
\usepackage{amssymb} % checkmark

\usepackage{showframe} % to show margins

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\sffamily\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{|P{0.2}|P{0.3}|P{0.2}|P{0.2}|P{0.1}|}
    \hline
    Datum & \Block{}{Lernbereich \\ \scriptsize (Sprechen, Grammatik, \\ \scriptsize Lesen, \dots{})} & Thema & Material & \LARGE\color{green}\checkmark  \\
    \hline
 \rule{0pt}{0.925\textheight}& & &  & \\ % add space until the end of the text area
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

**But** the first solution is more flexible. Allows you to insert horizontal lines, if you want.

Using the command `\replicate{<nn>}{<command>}` to replicate `command` `nn` times.

[image: xx]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}% needed <<<<  
\usepackage{nicematrix}% needed <<<<

\usepackage{amssymb} % checkmark    

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62178/161015
\newcommand{\replicate}[2]{%
\def\temp{}%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp #2}}%
\temp}

%\usepackage{showframe} % to show margins

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\sffamily\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}

\begin{document}
        
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{|P{0.2}|P{0.3}|P{0.2}|P{0.2}|P{0.1}|}
    \hline
    Datum & \Block{}{Lernbereich \\ \scriptsize (Sprechen, Grammatik, \\ \scriptsize Lesen, \dots{})} & Thema & Material & \LARGE\color{green}\checkmark  \\
    \hline
    \replicate{21}{ & &  & &\\ \hline}  % add lines
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

**And** also number the lines.

[image: nx]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}% needed <<<<  
\usepackage{nicematrix}% needed <<<<

\usepackage{amssymb} % checkmark

\newcounter{rowcount}
    \setcounter{rowcount}{1}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62178/161015
\newcommand{\replicate}[2]{%
    \def\temp{}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp #2}}%
    \temp}

%\usepackage{showframe} % to show margins

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\sffamily\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}

\begin{document}        
            
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{|P{0.1}|P{0.15}|P{0.25}|P{0.2}|P{0.2}|P{0.1}|}
    \hline
\#  & Datum & \Block{}{Lernbereich \\ \scriptsize (Sprechen, Grammatik, \\ \scriptsize Lesen, \dots{})} & Thema & Material & \LARGE\color{green}\checkmark  \\
    \hline
    \replicate{21}{\therowcount\stepcounter{rowcount} & & &  & &\\ \hline}  % add numbered rows & lines
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: How did you figure out this crazy sequence? `\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter`

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner Taken from egreg answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62177/copy-table-row-n-times/62178#62178